# I was just attacked by an onslaught of downvotes! What do I do?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes, abuse, serial-voting

Checking my recent activity, I noticed that [nearly] all of my posts were downvoted within a short span of a few minutes. It seems as though I've been the victim of a systematic downvoting spree.

What can I do if I suspect that someone has downvoted all my posts in retaliation or revenge? Is there something in place that will stop this kind of voting abuse? Do I have any possible avenues of recourse?

Comment: Doesn't look random to me--they look systematic!

Comment: Well yes, of course. They're systematic because they appear to come from one single user, but they're random because the questions and answers that were downvoted seemed picked at random (except of course they were all mine).

Comment: Was nowhere near your questions, mate!

Comment: @random Answers man. Those were answers.

Comment: The good news is... I have tracked what I believe to be the culprit. I will discuss it with the team... I also **think** (not sure) that those downvotes have been cancelled.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I suppose I'll never know who's responsible for this, will I? BTW: the downvotes are still there. I don't really mind, but I'd hate to see it happen every day though.

Comment: His account on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/users/113570/philippe-leybaert

Comment: Lol just happened to me! Almost all my answers and questions have been downvoted lol

Comment: Happened to me 'bout an hour ago - 4 downvotes on my highest answers, inside of a minute.  Yet to see a reversal, but do the downvoters get their rep back too?

Comment: Nice "screenshot"...

Comment: s/random/arbitrary/

Comment: See also: [Serial Downvoting Victim](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28756)

Comment: Hey, I'm also in a situation of constant downvotes for no reason at all...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It just looks like you have gotten on the wrong side of somebody, and they have went on a downvoting rage against you.

SO runs scripts and checks for this kind of behaviour every 24 hours, so it should be fixed up soon.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but after checking all the downvoted answers, I couldn't find anything that could trigger this kind of behavior. The human race is a weird bunch of animals sometimes :)

Comment: True that.  Someone, somewhere, was so unhappy with you that they said to themselves *"I'll show him!"* and went off on a down vote rampage.

Comment: The downvotes disappeared. Either the script has just run, or someone intervened and removed the downvotes (Or the downvoter came to his senses)

Comment: The downvoter couldn't "come to his senses" since the vote reversal time limits were in play -- unless you'd edited every single one of those questions & answers. However, I am glad the script is working out nicely there. Revenge downvoters suck.

Answer (score 49):

[image]

Answer (score 14):

As already stated, there are automated processes to watch for this. Checking in a few places (your "recent" tab on SO, Jon's SO tracker, etc), it looks like this may have already been undone by the system.

If you think there is still a problem, flag for a ♦ moderator (or add a comment here), or e-mail the team (page footer). BTW; it makes it easier to investigate if you associate your SO/MSO accounts, plus you get free rep ;-p

Comment: It happened again half an hour ago. I took your advice and e-mailed team@stackoverflow.com. This is really sick.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/113570/philippe-leybaert

Comment: or add a comment here? Some fellow just downvoted me a grip for downvoting one of his posts after commenting to me on it that it's a past-time of his to downvote people who downvote him.. Think you could fix it up for me?

Comment: @Jimmy: You might be interested in this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108538/133368

Comment: @Marc: Today I got serial downvotes, and I was looking for a moderator, I found yourself, Please let me know, what can I do in this situation.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya dealt with, thanks

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks Mark for reversing. Seeking another help - is there any way to know, who is/are the serial downvoter(s)?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya by *me* (and ♦ mods), yes: and I've already contacted the individual(s) responsible on the matter.

Comment: @MarcGravell Someone went on a downvoting spree yesterday and I was in their crosshair. It's been over 24h since it happened so do you mind taking a look at it when you got the time?

Answer (score 9):

Serial-downvoting is a consequence of any anonymous community -- and there are systems in place to combat it. It is frowned upon, and I'm sure that if the user did it repeatedly they'd be asked (politely) to stop.

If you feel you've been the target of serial downvoting, flag one of your posts for moderator attention, and ask for a rep-recalc.

Also, there's an automated system that performs a vote 'undo' when a certain pattern of downvoting is seen, this could also be triggered.

Comment: Attribution? That's George's answer, lock stock and barrel. :)

Comment: And, that is exactly why you should upvote it rather than disrespectfully down-voting. Do it for Georgie.

Comment: I wasn't your downvoter here.

Comment: Why was this downvoted, its not wrong and has some useful tips/info.

Comment: @EvanCarroll +1 for Georgie

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you made enemies with some other user who is now downvoting your stuff. Contact the team (Contact us link at the bottom) so that they can reverse it any educate that user about the penalty-box.

**Edit:** Or not, wasn't aware of the automated checks. Leaving this here just as a sign of what not to do.

Comment: Philippe should wait to contact them.  joshhunt is correct...SO is actively looking for these behaviors and it very well may be remedied soon.

Answer (score 1):

Just suffered a similar "storm of downvotes" myself, in the space of one-two minutes about an hour ago -- "just" nine of them, in my case, not twenty like Philippe had, but similarly "random fury" (the downvoter hit several of my questions and a random-ish sample of my answers).  I will patiently wait for the cleansing script to run, and hope the script in question doesn't have a threshold of ten to identify "sabotage downvotes"!-).

Comment: Oi, don't go throwing names around like that willy-nilly.

Comment: I have a sudden urge to rename myself.

Comment: ...and the script has apparently done its job now, the "sabotage downvotes" are gone.

Answer (score 1):

Happening to me (second time) now... this time it seams like a *reply* to a comment I did (just pointed a little error in the answer code). First time was because of a downvote I did (60% - 80% fixed).

But who cares, I lost 10+ received 100... and someone else got his *revenge* for my - just wanted to help - comment.

EDIT 2010-01-01:
seams like someone really got hurt :-(
5 additional down-votes this night/yesterday...
kind of childish.

Comment: If it's a significant amount it'll get picked up by the automated systems and the down-votes removed and the rep restored.

Comment: I think there's no need, seams like the down-votes where removed (eventually 2 left).