# What to do against trolls downvoting all personal questions

Tags: support, stack-overflow, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial Downvoting Victim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim)

Sometimes people obviously dislike answers and instead of downvoting my answers they will also massively downvote *all* of my other questions. This is playing war. How to deal with that?

Comment: Do avoid words like idiot, lazy, lame, blather in your comments.  Be nice.

Comment: Some (shortened) comments of yours: `i can read question and i can read existing solutions, dude.`, `This is truly the lamest solution`, `Are you too lazy to google`, `your comment is only laughable.`,`Don't be LAZY!` ... take a breath, the enemy is not at sight

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sit back and relax.

We have a daily job that picks up on this kind of abuse and invalidates votes from people who are on a mission to ruin your day.