# What can be done about down-voting harassment

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, spam-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial Downvoting Victim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim)

Today I downvoted an answer and posted a comment stating something along the lines of "-1 should be a comment" to a user whose answer told the OP to show what he had done so far (Can't find the location, assuming it's deleted)
This is what resulted:

```
-36  Today
-2   55 mins ago    downvote    Cryptographic mechanisms
-2   57 mins ago    downvote    .NET webbrowser control automation
-2   57 mins ago    downvote    consuming multiple clients of the same C# webservice from different remote locations
-2   59 mins ago    downvote    What is the very last event fired off during creation of a silverlight page
-2   59 mins ago    downvote    haskell division type mismatch?
-2   1 hour ago downvote    from clause issue with mysql
-2   1 hour ago downvote    help me define process and procedure?
-2   1 hour ago downvote    String manipulation - Can this be made better?
-2   1 hour ago downvote    Which language to learn as a student
-2   1 hour ago downvote    Arrays in Java - Core Java
-2   1 hour ago downvote    What is the most efficient way to store a non-directed graph?
-2   1 hour ago downvote    comparing strings in java
-2   1 hour ago downvote    Landau Notation: Sum of Big O <= Big O of Sum
-2   1 hour ago downvote    Fibonacci sequence
-2   1 hour ago downvote    RSA trick in email reply
-2   1 hour ago downvote    Simple threading question
-2   1 hour ago downvote    Java Multi-Level Break
-2   1 hour ago downvote    C# generics - Can I make T be from one of two choices?
```

As well as some comments on my answers/questions that are not constructive or relevant.
Personally I find this really immature and don't think it's behavior that we should encourage on SE.

Are there any safeguards to prevent vindictive behavior?

Comment: I had even searched for duplicates and wasn't able to find them :/

Comment: *Today I downvoted an answer and posted a comment stating something along the lines of "-1 ...* <-- that, don't do that. Voting is anonymous - you should be able to figure out *why* now. As for the votes... They'll be reversed (see the question I closed this as a duplicate of). And don't call other users out on Meta unless you're trying to escalate things - flag for moderator attention or send a private email if necessary.

Comment: I commented so that the user would know why he got down-voted, as the site suggests when you do so.

Comment: @Jean: yes, by all means, leave constructive comments when you down-vote. But don't prefix them with "-1 " - that doesn't add anything useful, it just rubs the author's face in the fact that you down-voted him. Some folks are... real babies about that.

Comment: @Jean-BernardPellerin: In future, just flag a non-question for mod attention.  We'll take care of his dopey butt.

Comment: -1 Should have checked for dupes first

Comment: Do as @Won't says. Don't downvote non-questions or non-answers. Flag 'em.