# Gaming the mass downvotes

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial Downvoting Victim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim)

Once again I think I've pissed someone off. Instead of massive downvoting all my answer, the other party only downvotes 3 per day. Is there something I can do to counter that?

Comment: I don't see where this is happening in your profile.

Comment: This has already been answered. There's an answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim) as to what you can do about serial downvoting.

Comment: In the future just flag one of your posts. I've identified the user and will deal with it.

Comment: 9 mins reaction, you guys rock =)