# Victim of Revenge Downvoting

Tags: discussion, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial Downvoting Victim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim)

I've seen a lot of posts about revenge downvoting suggesting one of two responses:

1. Let the system take care of it in its daily process
2. Flag for moderator attention

I've waited a couple days and it's still showing up, and unfortunately, I'm confused what precisely I am supposed to be flagging for moderator attention.  My own answers?  In any case, if you [look at my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189950/kirk-woll?tab=reputation), it's pretty obvious which votes I'm alluding to:

[image]

I am almost certain it was due to sour feelings from a comment I made to a question posted by [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/617027/tom):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921071/alter-content-of-sms-message-before-it-is-sent

(Note that this post is deleted so requires 10k+ rep. to view)

Sorry for wasting poeple's time on something inconsequential like this, but revenge voting always leaves a bad taste in my mouth.

Comment: At this point, there's not sufficient activity to clearly determine revenge down voting. However, if this pattern continues even slightly, there _will_ be. If you see it happen again, flag _immediately_ so that we can see it while it's happening (and before the system possibly invalidates those votes automatically).

Comment: @Tim, thanks for responding.  Ultimately I don't mind too much either way, it's really not a big deal.  But if you could, would it be possible to elaborate why there's not sufficient information to figure  out the truth of this?  Is it simply a matter of policy that investigation into voting patterns requires a higher threshold? (which is fine and understandable)  Or is it actually that the data isn't there?  (I can verify with certainty that the system hasn't corrected this situation, at least, and it seems beyond doubt that this is serial down-voting.)

Comment: I'm all too aware of revenge downvoting on SO. I, also, posted an answer a week ago which drew ~40 downvotes in just a few hours. Sock puppets? Cliques? My answer wasn't even that bad, and fully explained my position. But it seemed to grate against a prevailing subjective opinion. Ever since, I've been getting a down vote on every new question I post. It just happened again, a few minutes ago on a question I posted yesterday. That never happened before. I filed a complaint with SO support, but they don't seem to be helpful, but rather are giving me the same stock reply you seem to be getting.

Comment: @InfiniteLoop, I only see one of your last 10 questions with a downvote. Perhaps SO has corrected this for you?

Comment: @KirkWoll there were some recent upvotes that masked the downvotes. For example, one question that had been sitting idle for one month (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750812/woocommerce-composite-products-trying-to-set-sku-on-variation-gives-variation-s) suddenly received three consecutive downvotes over night. SO replied "nothing unusual". At first I thought SO had auto-corrected, but it might also have been normal upvote activity by "normal" members. I can almost guaranty that if I ask a question today, it will be downvoted by tomorrow. That never used to happen to me before last week.

Comment: @KirkWoll Notice this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750812/woocommerce-composite-products-trying-to-set-sku-on-variation-gives-variation-s It has -2. It was -3. It took three downvote hits overnight, the day following an answer with an alter-p.o.v. that "angered" a meta group. Someone upvoted it, so now it shows -2, but for a question to sit for one month doing nothing, and suddenly get 3 downvotes in one night, I'm calling foul. I reported suspicious behavior, but StackOverflow either doesn't care, or for all I know I'm reporting it to the vandals who are doing it.

Comment: @Tarkus - IMHO, don't take the situation so seriously. And REALLY think through what you are doing, before making comments like "*for all I know I'm reporting it to the vandals who are doing it*". Man, that's being *way* too suspicious / conspiracy-minded! IMHO, Offensive to the hard-working moderators.  Better to take the attitude that what you've encountered is, so far, too minor for anyone to spend their precious time on. (Though let me say I deeply sympathize with what you encountered - even a single retaiiatory downvote really bothers me. Trying to follow my own advice to shrug it off.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I provided examples to back up my hypotheses. A question that goes unnoticed for 6 months to a year, then receives 3 downvotes within hours after posting an opposite (and unpopular) opinion, well, you do the math.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Flagging for moderator attention is simply a way to communicate directly with the diamond ♦ moderators.

Flag one of your *own* questions and explain the situation. It doesn't matter which question you actually flag, but it will make it a bit easier on the mods if you flag **one** of the questions which is in question. Don't flag them all; One is enough.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, flag one of your answers and ask the moderator to look into the voting patterns.  That's one of the options [listed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim/28758#28758).

You can also email team@stackoverflow.com.