# What to do about harassment?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, sock-puppets

This morning I happened to disagree with some newbie user on the best way to resolve a question. He suggested that it is absolutely the best way to directly access a static field in another class; where I told him that this would be bad practice; and that a good design would avoid using fields directly, and static fields even more.

In the end, the newbie-questioner accepted the answer by that other newbie.

Now to my question: checking my reputation right now, I see that I got like 20 "-2" downvotes on some different recent answers. And you know, not only one downvote, but two. And surprise: that question/answer from those two newbies ... vanished too.

My gut feeling is something like: I upset some sock puppet and his master; and now he is pulling the big "revenge" trigger by downvoting stuff of mine.

Long story short: can I do something about that? If so, what could I do about it?

I don't think that this is a duplicate of [How should I handle possible revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106704), as it talks about getting *single* downvotes as revenge. Mine is about downvotes in plural. Even plurals!

Comment: Short answer: That's serial voting. There is a system in place that detects and reverses that activity. Generally speaking, you don't need to worry about it; it should be reversed by tomorrow.

Comment: @AlE. Thanks. I like your comment more than that possible duplicate, which talks about SINGLE downvotes. Which is not exactly the same as 20 downvotes in 10 minutes. Just wondering: will there be any consequences for the serial-voter?

Comment: Not generally, no.

Comment: @AlE. That last point; I find very discouraging. Is there at least a way for me to figure the ID of the serial-downvoter?

Comment: Nope. That's non-public information.

Comment: So, in other words: there are checks, and bans, and effort to keep up the quality of questions and answers; but even when the system detects such an event of "bullying" ... well, doesn't matter, "victim, get over" it!? Too bad, I had hoped that a community of geeks and nerds, making such experiences far too often in their real life ... would come up with something better than "life with it".

Comment: Not so much "live with it", rather than "don't worry, we've got this". And if the "bully" would be persistent, you can always flag for moderator attention. Flag any content of yours with the "other" flag option and explain what's going on. Moderator can then (if necessary) escalate the problem higher up and see if anything else needs to happen besides the automated systems.

Comment: No need for sock puppets of any kind. Single user can downvote up to 30 posts per day (or 40? Doesn't really matter), even they're all by the same user.

Comment: Well. If he gets smarter, he might decide to upvote one, two postings per week. And i would have no idea about that. And the system wouldnt detect that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That is true. I miscompued there; I guess it is only one user downvoting me. But I still find it interesting, that not only his **answer** vanished, but the whole question that triggered our argument.

Comment: @GhostCat you're not the first: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227845/undetectable-micro-serial-downvoting-what-is-it-what-to-do-what-the-heck.

Comment: If voting is indistinguishable from fair voting behaviour ... there isn't a problem. But even in the case of persistent, unexplained trickle voting, feel free to flag. It has happened to me in the past. And while I never got direct feedback, I know the situation was looked into and evaluated. Bottom line, bullying, in whatever form, is never accepted.

Comment: @GhostCat as 10k rep user, you can see the deleted question and who deleted it. Search your browser history, it should still be there.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Great idea about browser history. And I learned: that question was deleted "by community"; and maybe that got that other newbie mad, as he lost the 15 rep he received for his accepted answer. So, thanks for reminding me on my own powers ;-)

Comment: Cheers, that's what we're here for... ;)

Comment: The system works; even better than the comments here suggested:  *This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities. The suspension period ends in 7 days* ( http://stackoverflow.com/users/6559239/utkarsh-dubey ) ...

Comment: Probably someone flagged, moderator took a look, and pushed the suspend button. Cheers! :)

Comment: Hail to the unknown flagger and moderator. Cheers!

Comment: and you were even right about sock puppets: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:7A071ltK8kkJ:stackoverflow.com/users/6559288/utkarsh-dubey+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk (he even suggested edits on his own posts and approved, to boost reputation) All in all, just a troll - better off without such users.

Comment: Really? Am I a *bad* person as I feel inclined to ROFL LOL feel delighted by now?

Comment: Schadenfreude for trolls is a delightful feeling.