# Any way to prevent downvotes spamming?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial Downvoting Victim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim)

There is a user who has downvoted 15 of my answers and questions within the last 10 minutes. Any way to prevent downvote spamming like this?

Comment: I took care of the problem that you reported. Additionally, this topic has come up [quite a bit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=revenge+downvoting). Flagging was the appropriate thing to do.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Sorry I missed the dupe.