# Banned from posting questions on SO, caused by Spam downvoting

Tags: support, post-ban, low-quality-posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi)

Hey guys yesterday and today I've had a few people who I will not express my anger at them in French... who have been spam downvoting me

Could this be why I cannot post any questions on SO?

Comment: Downvote is not spam. It means someone think your post has poor quality. If your posts will be good, they will get upvotes - simple as that. This said, if you think you got downvotes as retaliation to something you said to someone (e.g. in chat) please email the team (team@stackoverflow.com) with the names of those people and what they said to you, and they will check it out. In the meantime, you can try and give good productive answers, once you reach enough answers with upvotes the ban will be also lifted.

Comment: not if they go through all of your posts and downvote every single one.. that is therefore called Downvote SPAMMING!!!

Comment: Such thing is identified by the system and those downvotes are removed, give it couple of days. Happened to me and to many others. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting) as well..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you've hit the post quality ban. Improve your posts.

Pro tip: use proper capitalization.

```
i really hate it when people cant use proper capitalization

and proper punctuation

lol
```