# How can I lift a question ban caused by a serial downvoter?

Tags: support, serial-voting, post-ban

I was serial downvoted by someone (not sure who). A few hours later, the system automatically banned me from posting questions.

I read the following...

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi/86998#86998)

... which did not mention anything about serial downvoting, only that downvoting in general is a factor in this.

I am *not* aware from all the reading I have done how to correctly approach this issue and don't want to waste anyone's time, hence my question here.

So, what is the best route to resolve a question ban induced by a serial downvoter?

Comment: When did the serial downvoting happen?

Comment: Have you deleted any questions?

Comment: I entered a couple (appropriate) up-votes, in case those help. I would be slightly surprised to find that serial-down-voting alone could result in a question ban.

Comment: Alenanno Earlier this afternoon over a span of a range of four minutes. @Andrew Baerber I don't think I've deleted anyone's questions? Didn't know I could. Thanks for your help Andrew!

Comment: You can delete your own questions. Deleting your own questions that were downvoted is a bad thing if done too many times.

Comment: Oh I see the option now, thanks.

Comment: @galacticninja he specifically said how it didn't help him. It's not a dupe.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/162827)

Comment: Related (for Stack Overflow): *[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers...”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/)*

Comment: Related: [All deleted questions/answers are now shown to their authors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/374184#374184)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If they were serial downvotes then they will very likely be removed by the system within 24 hours (usually a bit after 03:00 UTC) and the posts restored to their original scores. This should allow you to post again. If the serial downvotes are not automatically reversed after 24 hours, then see [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)

However, there is a wider issue here. If you are that close to a question ban then you should address some of the issues with your posts as outlined in that answer.

In the meantime look for some questions you can **answer**. Provide good answers (i.e., ones that get upvotes) which will only help your standing in the community.

Comment: I've read the issues stated and they don't seem to apply. There are ten total down-votes with only nine of my questions actually having negative scores (someone noticed this and up-voted one of my questions). All the down-votes where on questions asked by me. Also I do make a modest attempt to answer questions, I'll just try to answer some questions in the meantime. I'll see what happens and accept the answer later if it seems to work out.

Comment: I think this is a fairly dismissive answer. Yes, it's possible that a user who's been serially-downvoted deserves a question ban. It's also possible that they don't, and I'm not comfortable with this answer coming from a moderator. Scenario: user has three questions, all with one up-vote. User is downvoted twice on each question, by two different (retailiating) users. Those votes will likely not be caught by the abusive-voting script. User is banned from asking questions. This is a somewhat-theoretical question (necessarily so, given that script details are secret), but not by much.

Comment: No, it's pretty clear that this was by the same person, the timestamps for all ten down-votes are over a range of four minutes.

Comment: Accepted, I'm going to have to presume the system has a lag of over an hour as I was able to go to the question page without the ban though the down-votes were only removed almost two hours later. That's fine, I imagine that some direct human involvement took place. Thanks for your answer.