# Victim of serial downvoting banned after serial downvoting reversed

Tags: support, post-ban

I was serial downvoted yesterday, today I've earned my reputation back, but I discovered that I've got banned.
Was it because of the serial downvoting?

Comment: Yes. [Serial Voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) is forbidden.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: Hmm? Surely *being* serially downvoted isn't forbidden.

Comment: Are you saying you are still banned, or you *were* banned until the serial downvoting was reversed?

Comment: The OP was serially downvoted yesterday, and as a result was question banned. Even though the votes were reversed, they are still banned. I'm pretty sure this is their question (at least, that's how I read it).

Comment: Sorry, did over read the `I was` part.

Comment: @Matt, I haven't created a question since I've got serial down-voted, today when it was reversed, I've tried to post a question, and I was banned

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi you got it right :)

Comment: It's fairly unlikely that they you are still question-banned *because of the serial voting*. Likely you *are* banned and the serial voting is just a coincidence. If it just occurred recently, then you are probably very close to the threshold (keep in mind that one of the downvotes yesterday *did not* get reversed).

Comment: Ah! it happened to you too. How many others I wonder, who just wander off into the cold night and get forgotten.

Answer (score 24):

I think in your case, the reason for the question ban was the 6 questions you deleted over the last couple of days, seemingly in response to the serial downvoting. I've undeleted these, which should be enough to return you back over the threshold.

I've also issued a warning to the person targeting you with these downvotes, because you weren't the only one they were going after.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the system that does the question banning and the system that does the question-unbanning are not 100% synced up with the voting system.  There's likely some caching involved.

This should theoretically fix itself in a few hours or a few days, but if you can't wait that long, you could flag one of your posts for moderator attention, and then use the "Other" option to explain that you were serially downvoted, which triggered the ban, then when the votes were reversed, the ban stuck.

As others have mentioned, and as [ChrisF mentions here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122131/155826), if you're that close to a question ban where some serial downvotes push you over the edge, you might consider using this opportunity to edit and beef up some of your posts. This will not only help reverse the ban but also help prevent another one in the future, should some unsavory individual decide to go on a downvoting rampage.