# What to do about obvious group of malicious downvotes

Tags: support, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)

Please see the screenshot.  For some reason or another, it seems somebody clicked on a handful of my questions/answers and just rapidly downvoted them (all 9 downvotes we within a 1 minute time period).

Is there anything that can be done about this?  Is this common?  Can this sort of thing be reported?

[image]

Comment: Keep half an eye on the profile of the users you help.  If their bio does sound particularly psycho then just steer clear of them.  These downvotes will disappear within the next 24 hours.