# What if a user targets another user personally?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)

If one user purposefully downvotes another user's questions and answers due to some personal grudge or something, can this be tracked and avoided?

Comment: @Danielδ I do all the time, that's an extremely minor spelling mistake for an non native English speaker...

Comment: Thanks Yannis. :) I'm sorry. Will never again try to post a question on meta again. And yeah even on SO it is very difficult for a new comer who is trying to understand what SO is (or bad at English) to get some rep because of the down votes.

Comment: @Katti: Please do not take meta downvotes personally.  See [the FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) on the difference between votes in meta and votes in main sites.  You happened to post a duplicate question; that's perfectly understandable.

Comment: Yeah the reason was my search couldn't fetch that duplicate Question.

Comment: As I said, that's understandable.  I've inadvertently [posted duplicates](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A164012+closed%3A1) as well.  Sometimes you find out after the fact.