# Report serial down-voting on my profile

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting, reporting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)

As you can clearly see here:

( Not allowed yet to post images, here's the link: [downvotes](http://ictech.fr/ictech/downvotes.jpg) )

in my [Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1438628/jidma?tab=reputation), **all** of my questions have been down voted the same minutes regardless of their content or quality.

How can i report this ?

Comment: Wait until the next day to see whether it is reverted (there is an automatic script that checks for serial up/down voting). If not, report here.

Comment: By posting here, you've already reported it. I've warned the culprit now, so all that's left is to wait for the script to return you your rep.

Comment: OK i'll wait another 12 hours for the automatic script to do it's job.
Thank you sir !

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn : two days have passed now but I still haven't got my reputation back. Is this normal?

Comment: I see "Serial upvoting reversed" in your reputation tab - http://stackoverflow.com/users/1438628/jidma?tab=reputation

Comment: Yep that's true. Thank s a lot