# Will the downvote-abuse script ever be able to catch downvotes cast over an extended period of time?

Tags: support, down-votes, abuse

After an argument in the comments and chat, a certain user is downvoting my every answer. I'm posting approximately 1 answers/day, and she is downvoting every one of them.

Will the abuse-catch script be able to catch her at this pace?

- If yes, when?
- If no, what other measures should I try?

Comment: The Islam site in general [doesn't sound like a very friendly place](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/6258/why-a-separate-site-for-shia-is-necessary). I plain can't imagine it succeeding as a community.

Comment: How do you know it's the same user?

Comment: @Mat: It all started after that argument. I'm following her activity; I'm getting the down-votes at the same time around she is active. I argued about this in the chat, she didn't answer but also couldn't deny it, she just changed the topic.

Comment: Ok, well I don't think this is something that the automatic abuse script will catch (could be wrong though). You should bring this to the attention of that site's mods, or use the "contact us" thing to reach SE staff - I don't think there's much anyone can do besides mods & higher-ups.

Comment: I'm taken back to my days in the kindergarten. "See, he punched me!" then "No, he started". We are not kindergarten. If you see the automatic script doesn't work after 3 days, use the proper channels of flagging one of your own posts that was downvoted and explaining. Moderators have tools to check those things.

Comment: On second read of the question and my answer I might have been to harsh, but still - did you even give it some time to see if you get the reputation back?

Comment: Reading the link that @animuson provided, what if this other user simply disagrees with what you're writing? The same user might be downvoting other answers (from *other* users) that provide the same different view?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Not moderators. Only the Team can check those things.

Comment: Though that might change, @Alenanno: [Give moderators a tool to invalidate votes between users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143951/give-moderators-a-tool-to-invalidate-votes-between-users) is status deferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct thing to do is to keep working and contributing and see about entering a dialog with your moderation team on the site. Just flag one of your answers or ask this on your site's meta and your moderation team can set up a private chat room to avoid publicly accusing anyone of improper voting.

From a systematic, site-wide perspective, be assured that the system works better when long term patterns arise and the vote script is there to catch totally over the top behavior or short term misbehavior before the normal tools can be effective. If someone or some group of people consistently down vote one person, it will get flagged for your moderation team whether the time period is short or long.

You want to be open to the possibility that it's not simply bad acting, but do reach out to your specific site's moderation team. In the short term - just keep on participating in the site and engage your team of moderators when something feels really off in your reputation stream.

Comment: Why do officeworkers say "reach out" now instead of simply contact?  It seems so new-agey.

Comment: [People](http://www.theofficelife.com/business-jargon-dictionary-R.html) [with](http://www.forbes.com/sites/groupthink/2012/01/26/the-most-annoying-pretentious-and-useless-business-jargon/3/) [annoyingly](http://www.forbes.com/pictures/ekij45gdh/most-annoying-business-jargon/) [Dilbertish](http://www.itsyourbiz.com/home/featured-stories/Business-Jargon-Just-Get-to-the-Point-125638918.html) [business](http://finance.yahoo.com/news/the-most-annoying--pretentious-and-useless-business-jargon.html) [jargon](http://www.thedailymuse.com/career/business-jargon/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will probably be able to handle downvotes spread over multiple days. [It happened a few days ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144618/does-serial-voting-cause-the-voter-a-reputation-change)

Comment: Though the linked post refers to reversing upvotes in a voting ring, I guess you may be right. Nice.