# Down voted multiple questions simultaneously even upvoted some?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)

I'm very much disappointed by seeing around 7 questions been asked by me were down voted by somebody.
Some of them are up voted too.
I want to know reason why at the same time down voted 7 questions.  These questions are genuine and replied to me someone.I accepted their answer too.
Some of them are
[Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506563/html-color-to-alternative-rows-of-dynamic-table)
[Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608152/using-jndi-in-spring-with-was)
[Question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557527/adding-an-image-to-a-tif-file-in-java)
Any one can help me..?

Comment: Without passing any judgement on question that I have not read *"These questions are genuine and replied to me someone"* says nothing about their suitability for the site in question. They might be good questions in a general sense and still be bad questions for Stack Overflow.

Comment: your [reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1468481/mr-chowdary?tab=reputation) looks like about 7 hours ago you were [serially downvoted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting "answers to this question explain what to do in cases like this")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes (and almost certainly in this case) this is a [serial down-voting issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting) - did you upset anyone or get into an argument?

On the plus side, if the *same* user down-voted a bunch of your posts in a short time frame, this type of activity usually is caught by the system (and I believe the script runs once a day). Check back tomorrow and see if your reputation has been restored (your reputation history will say something like "Serial down-voting reversed").

That said, it could be just that you have bad questions, and the timing could be coincidence or it could be someone who visited your profile and then went to each of your questions and found them lacking. Hard for any of us regular peon users to tell, really. I do notice a common trend (not in every single question, but several) that many folks look down upon: you don't  show us what you've tried, so your questions kind of come off like "gimme teh codez." Not enough for me to also down-vote, but down-voting is a very subjective thing.