# Lot of downvotes in an instant

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I’m the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)

I'm not sure if this is a good question, but I don't have other place to get a good answer. In the last few days, I started receiving downvotes in different answers in an instance, it felt like someone going to my profile, check my answers and started downvoting for who knows a reason. What it really pisses me off is if this person has anything against me why just throw the rock and hide the hand! I would accept the downvotes if I wasn't right, but these answers were upvoted and some of them marked as the answer, so this problem really worries me. The last thing I could imagine is that SO blocks my account for many downvotes (I hope to be wrong here). What could I do to stop this?

Note: I'm not asking for a sniffer that will stop the downvotes or you to give me back the lost rep. I just want to know if I should really worry about SO blocking my account. The personal problem between people on SO and me is outside of this question.

Comment: "last few days"? I only see downvotes for today. Did you get into an argument with someone?

Comment: @Mysticial well I lost like 4 or more points Saturday too, that's when I started worrying. Not that I remember, I tend only to talk about professional matters, trying to not picking up a fight or similar.

Comment: 4-5 downvotes might not be enough to trigger the vote-reversal script. But since you're brought it up here, a mod will likely take a look at it.

Comment: Now I have 10 downvotes in a single day, all of them in different answers. It looks like someone really hates me or has started a crusade against me. IMO this is very childish because it is a professional place, not a children playground =\.

Comment: Ah, I see that you just got a few more of them. That's probably enough to trigger the script. But you'll have to wait up to 24 hours.

Comment: see: [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28756/165773)

Comment: I've found the culprit and sent him a warning. As stated in the duplicate link, the votes will be removed by an automated script sometime over the next day or so.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I'm so relieved. Thanks.

Comment: @gnat I didn't know about it, now it's one of my favorites questions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn sorry to bother again, but I'm having the same problem today, this time wasn't serial voting (the downvote rate was between prolonged rates) but it was downvoting even on possible answers (I guess there was nothing wrong on them). Should I just wait for the script to help me again or follow the 2nd and 3rd steps provided in the possible duplicate link?

Comment: It looks very much like serial downvoting. I'll handle it. The script will continue to work, so you don't have to worry too much about it. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag the post for moderator attention or mail the problem to `team@stackoverflow.com`. If something is wrong, they will most likely solve the problem.