# 3 question downvotes at once

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I’m the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)

Just got 3 downvotes at once for old, totally unrelated questions of mine:

- [Possible to scroll caret into view inside a single HTML text field with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892902)
- [Simple algorithm to crop empty borders from an image by code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083853)
- [Exception window in VS.NET 2010 is missing the "User-unhandled" column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560497)

Could this count as kind of a "vandalism" that I can do something against? Or at least see/know whether this was done by the same guy?

**Edit 2014-07-20**

Just for the record, here is another massive downvote happening today:

[image]

Someone seems to be *really* angry about me. I hope the automatic system will catch up on this.

**Edit 2014-07-21**

Yeah! The downvotes were automatically removed.

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that this might _not_ be serial downvoting, old posts get votes (up/down) all the time, it could just be coincidental.

Comment: Thanks, @YannisRizos Actually I never got _three_ at once, although this might be very well possible. Just rather improbable, IMHO.

Comment: It certainly looks suspicious, all three questions were last active more than a year ago.

Comment: They're also all notably posts that previously had +10/-0, and are now a total of 9, after the 1 negative each.

Comment: Why is this a public post and not a message to the moderators? We don't need armchair detectives weighing in.

Comment: @MikeB Most likely, because I have too few experiences in using SO/Meta. Please excuse me, I'm sorry if I offended you in any way.

Comment: @UweKeim I guess you could claim ignorance but it's like going back to a store because you had a problem with something you just bought and instead of having a discrete discussion with the manager you decided to shout your problems to the entire store and hope that someone will help you. Besides the information offered in this post (none since it's a duplicate) I don't understand why the mods keep it around.

Comment: @MikeB Thanks for your reply and sorry for posting my initial question.

Comment: Serial downvotes? Never heard of it. In any case, I put you a +1 to cover for that. :)

Comment: @MikeB: actually, that would be #3 for today. But thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be a serial-downvote. Wait for 36 hours, the script will be triggered it self. And the down-votes will be reversed.

If it is not reversed, you may flag one of the question to moderator's attention and ask them to check if it is a serial-downvote or not. Or you can contact team@stackoverflow.com.

[Have a look at this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28758/187824)

Comment: Wow, cool, great to know, thank you!

Comment: Wait about 2-3 days. If they aren't reversed, you can flag one of your posts for moderator attention and post a link to this discussion.