# Getting downvoted every time when I ask anything or post on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

When I ask any question on Stack Overflow I get downvoted every time over the past two days. Moreover I am not getting a proper reply to my questions and posts. This has an impact on my reputation.

For example see this:
[Show website activities on Facebook timeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249096/website-activities-on-facebook-timeline)

I have been greatly supported by one of the users and am really thankful to him. On the other hand, the question was downvoted.

May I know why this happens?

Comment: Downvotes without a comment explaining the reason are quite impolite. Not getting responses is likely due to asking the wrong questions, like ones with lots of code to plough through and no indication that you've researched the cause of problems yourself.

Comment: There are a number of reasons why you may get downvoted. If you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) regarding what type of questions are appropriate this may answer some reasons. Other reasons may be that you have not demonstrated any research of effort - for example "I want to do ... how do I do it" rather than "I want to do ... This is what I've tried so far ... This is what isn't working ... Can anyone help".

Comment: I'd also suggest that you should be prepared to be downvoted again as this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8):

I can only assume the down-vote was given because the question doesn't quite follow the guidance in the [FAQs](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

> "...We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them..."

And

> "...a specific programming problem..."

Having said that, you got more up-votes than down-votes so don't be too disheartened!

You are also doing quite well so far on this question.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that you read through the ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page.

One of the major parts of that page is the section "Do your homework". What it tells you is that you should search for your answer, and research your problem before asking your question here. Looking at the question [you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249096/website-activities-on-facebook-timeline), it fails in this regard. You might have done extensive research, but if so, you don't tell us.

In your question you state what you want. And though that is nice, it's not enough for us. A good question also contains "this is what I've researched", "this is what I've come up with" and ideally "this is what I've tried". The last part often being relevant code.

Then you have a good and appropriate question. Failing to include these parts does not mean you will never get an answer. After all, you did. However, you do run an increased risk of getting downvoted, or perhaps your question being closed for the appropriate reasons.

So if you want to avoid it, put some more effort into researching your own problem before bringing it to Stack Overflow. You'll see that your questions will significantly improve and that the response to them will be more positive.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't taken the time to read all of your questions to judge whether they are correct or not but after reading this:

"When I ask any question on Stack Overflow I get negative voting -2 every time from past two days."

I considered the possibility that you may have upset a certain user in the past or you are just the random victim of [serial downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting).

If you are a victim of serial down voting then the system will catch it eventually. But even if it is serial down voting, you should review the "[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" guide and make sure that you are posting proper questions.

Also before you ask more questions, scout out the website(s) (whichever SE websites you use) and find questions with lots of good/bad votes and get a general idea of what type of question is accepted by the community and what is looked down upon.

Comment: To be fair I'd consider downvoting the linked question for exactly the reason Bart states. This doesn't appear to be serial downvoting.

Comment: And several of the other questions are also fairly poor. I think the serial downvoting theory is unlikely in this case.

Comment: @ben  which is why I included the last 2 paragraphs. I wasn't too sure of the circumstances of the downvotes but he said all his questions get downvoted within two days, I thought that it was a possibility.