# What are SO's measures against personal hate?

Tags: support, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I’m the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)
>   [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

From my profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/604511/aitchnyu?tab=reputation

```
-2  5 hours ago     downvote    Solr: best ...
-2  5 hours ago     downvote    Solr More ...
-2  5 hours ago     downvote    Ranking or ...
```

It seems personal. And he is unfortunately encouraged by SO's vote-anonymity, and AFAIK escape any consequences.

Who do I report this to, a moderator, to investigate this? Does SE have measures (human or bot) to counter behavior like this?

Comment: I get that downvotes sting a bit, and you're probably a victim of serial downvoting, but _hate_? Really? Come on, trolls will troll, you can't really let stuff like that affect you.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: No wonder we keep getting so many "offensive" flags on posts that otherwise seem relatively harmless...

Comment: I called it "hate" as it was of a personal nature :-) And I am glad that SO handles it well.

Comment: Note that he, if it is a single person, is getting minus points too. SO is designed to "hurt" whenever someone downvotes. That is if they care about their own points. Now, not sure anonymity is guaranteed as it is possible to make sql queries on a site somewhere and I think SO archives are available as a download.