# What do I do when someone deliberately downvotes many of my answers?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, users, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I’m the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)
>   [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

I followed a bunch of links [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting/28758#28758) and found helpful advice on what to do on this subject, but should there not be a way for me to notice this and immediately report it?

In my case, (I will not name names here, since that does not serve the community) I down voted someone, explained my reason in a comment, and even mentioned that I had down voted them, within a few minutes, many of my answers and questions from all around the site were down voted.

It seems very frustrating to have to flag each individual post, also, it is misleading...

I’ve not been on this site long, but I suggest there should be some other solution to this, possibly a report-malicious-activity button or something, something not specific to a question/answer/user just something on the side, where you can then explain, or give a link to a user/answer/question/comment/chat, etc.

Yes, I know this is a duplicate of many other questions that came before me, and I am sorry for that, but shouldn’t that solidify the reasoning for a solution?

I believe this user might be using multiple accounts for this, because I am starting to get more down votes on the same answers / questions.

Comment: So many downvotes, the vote fraud detection script will probably pick it up, and reverse it (See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/).

Comment: @RobW What does that script do ? How does it work ?

Comment: @AshRj They specifically don't explain how it works so that users cannot intentionally do just not enough for it to catch it.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your rep history

```
 
-2  16 mins ago     downvote    how to import matplotlib in python
-2  16 mins ago     downvote    Fastest way to get sorted unique list in python?
-2  16 mins ago     downvote    Efficiently deleting and checking lists
-2  16 mins ago     downvote    Python and regex - how to find anytext_NUMBER_svm.pkl
-2  16 mins ago     downvote    how to split a long line into multiple lines in python
-2  16 mins ago     downvote    Searching a CSV file using Regular Expressions
-2  16 mins ago     downvote    Python output just shows blinking cursor
-2  16 mins ago     downvote    Processing a list of lists in Python
```

It almost certainly looks like serial voting. I'm sure the automated system will pick this up. That's what it's there for!

Comment: thanks, this puts my mind at ease, i was very hurt that someone would do this, and could not understand what to do about it. i felt like i had caught a thief red-handed, taken a photo of him, but had no way to contact the police.

Comment: In that analogy, the police are already hooked in to your camera, see that a crime has been comitted, returns the stolen goods and repremands the theif all without you doing anything ;)

Comment: Not fraud, just serial. Fraud is when single person use multiple accounts to vote (either up or down) on the same post more than once.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - There is the possibility that both are happening to this user. There's been another raft of downvotes in the last minute or 2.

Comment: yes, another series of downvotes just hit me...

Comment: @jamiec Are any of the downvotes on the same post?  If not, then it's highly unlikely that it's fraud.