# I know somebody who is downvoting my posts across all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I’m the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)
>   [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

I know somebody who is downvoting my posts across all Stack Exchange sites. [And I have good reason to believe that there's a second downvoter as well.]

As you'd imagine, I'm sick and tired of this child's play.
Can I submit this information to the Stack Exchange team so that they can roll back the downvotes and make sure that this doesn't happen again?

Comment: You know that how precisely?

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I looked through your top accounts and didn't see any recent downvotes...

Comment: Comments are attached to the posts that are downvoted. Then, I looked at a few posts which were deleted. Guess what? Same people there too. // It's like I'm back in grammar school all over again!

Comment: If you suspect something like this and the votes aren't reversed after a day or two from the script that reverses serial downvoting, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to email team@stackexchange.com with the details (dates, post links, etc) and have them investigate the matter a bit more and reverse the votes if you're correct.

Comment: @animuson: Could you please look at my Workplace.SE and Politics.SE accounts? I think you'll find all the evidence there.

Comment: I'm sorry, but even on those accounts I don't see any severe or extraordinary downvoting happening.

Comment: @JimG: Well, if they're deleted then only moderators would be able to browse those posts. But your most recent downvote (still visible) on Workplace is for a post which is at -4, so there's nothing oddly suspicious about that.

Comment: @JimG. I have to agree with Bart. Serial downvoting is usually one or possibly two users downvoting all your posts, regardless of post quality or accuracy. The downvotes I see on your Politics and Workplace profile looks like there's only a handful of questions with many downvotes, which generally means the community thinks the answer is incorrect or a low quality answer for their site.

Comment: FWIW, a quick glance doesn't show any serial voting, or evidence that the same people are voting across different sites. If you have any evidence that contradicts this, please send it to us privately per Anna's instructions and we'll investigate.

Comment: @Shog9: Thanks, Shog. When I suspect this behavior again, I'll record it immediately. If I accumulate a sufficient number of these incidents, I'll notify the StackExchange team.

Comment: I believe that the OP got a point,that's not normal: http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/3417/screenshot20130107at102.png

Comment: @Ramy Al Zuhori: Thanks so much. I feel like the serial downvoter is being strategic to the extent that he/she isn't tripping the automated serial downvoting rules.

Comment: Even on SO, that's more than one (or two) users, @Ramy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the "contact us" link that's at the bottom of any page. (Not in the "HOW DID YOU NOT KNOW IT'S THERE" sense, but rather just saying that you don't have to go hunting for it.)

Give us as many details as you can such as dates and times of the votes, sites involved, and possible suspects if you have anyone in mind.

Comment: Thanks, Anna. Going forward, I will note suspicious downvoting patterns and forward this information to the StackExchange team.