# I swear someone is serially downvoting me

Tags: support, serial-voting

Look at my reputation history here on Meta:

[image]

Someone serially downvoted me. Ok. It was reversed. But now it looks like they noticed and took some precautions. Like not doing it in the same day. Is someone serially downvoting me?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the "what is serial voting". I know what serial voting is. This is a support question on "am I being serially voted?"

Comment: *<he's on to us!>* (have you flagged a post for moderator attention asking for them to look into it?)

Comment: This seems tactical downvoting. You should flag one of your post and explain there.

Comment: I'm noticing some 'Serial downvoting reversal' which suggests the automatic systems have noticed this and corrected. The script only runs once a day so todays may be reversed too

Comment: @Richard I mentioned that. I guess we'll have to wait and see.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I guess we'll see how clever the algorithm really is. In the mean time have +40 to tide you over

Comment: There would be a certain irony if the one and only downvoter here was your unnamed ‘friend’

Comment: You shouldn't swear.  That's rude.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I know somebody who is downvoting my posts across all Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161884/i-know-somebody-who-is-downvoting-my-posts-across-all-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: @JimG Except that I _don't_...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've checked things out, and I'm not seeing any patterns (which is all mods can see) - at least not yet. Keep an eye on things, and definitely don't hesitate to flag *if you see things getting worse over some more time*. Just keep in mind "Other" flags are our heaviest volume flags, so it may take a while for us to check them out. Which can work out better, anyway... as it would give more time for a pattern to form.

I wouldn't suggest flagging right now, but generally, flagging is better than a post here.

---

Ack! I see you meant *Meta*, not the main site. Things are *slightly* different here for you, but I'm still not seeing anything that looks too fishy just yet here, either. The same advice applies as above. Except that our flag volume overall here is extremely low, so such flags would be looked into much more quickly.

Also, re reversed votes: We also see the patterns as apply to those, so don't fear that votes being auto-reversed limits our abilities there.

---

Another couple notes on down voting on Meta; they are different in more ways than the typical ways people mention. First, voters here will *tend* to be somewhat more savvy and may try to keep things 'under the radar' (thanks to [Oded ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140505/oded) for that addition), but also the relative volume of posts to users here can have some effect. There are fewer posts and users, so there can tend to be higher amounts of people voting for the same people here than on the main site.

That said, we still don't like serial voting here, either. Just keep in mind the slight differences.

Comment: Downvoters on Meta would also tend to be more savvy regarding the Serial Downvote Detector and vote accordingly, trying to keep under the radar.

Comment: @oded man, that's too much work.  I just don't understand how someone can hold a grudge so long that they make much of a dent on someone else's reputation.  Sad, really.

Comment: @AdamDavis it's not hard to dent someone's reputation if he has 101 rep.

Comment: @JanDvorak It's not hard to post five good answers in 15 minutes and completely undo the work they took over several days to dent it, though.