# Can an account caught for serial down voting continue to cast downvotes on that single user?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting, account-suspension, ban

If a user account has been detected of serial down voting can that continue to cast downvotes on that single user?

The reverse can be asked about serial upvoting.

What happens to an account caught for serial voting; in terms of future votes upon individual accounts, voting in general and account suspension and/or deletion?

*I'm sorry if this is a dupe, I sis search and couldn't find the specific answer to this.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing happens. Most cases of serial voting are single-time occurrences that don't create repeat offenders and no further action is really required. In instances where a user continues the behavior against the same user, the user usually ends up flagging one of their posts for moderator attention so the behavior can be dealt with.

So a serial voting reversal does not in any way inhibit the user's ability to continue voting in any way. In fact, they could go vote for the *same* posts they serially voted before. Continued abuse will lead to a suspension, though (which does prevent them from voting).

Comment: I was systematically downvoted on [so] and this was finally picked up by the team, because I complained.. every time I would come online another couple of my posts would be downvoted (and they were different every time).. I have noticed this pattern occurs across some of my [se] accounts.. and it really pees me off. It undermines the principle of floating quality to the top, as it is cutting off posts, irregardless of merit. I've noticed it slowly starting on a new site, where I have upvoted good posts and then an old one is downvoted, not bumped posts..

Comment: You had the right to complain. The script can only pick up the blatant cases; it's certainly not perfect. The only thing you *can* do in a case like that is flag for a moderator or contact the team directly (which is better if it's cross-site). If you're suspicious, it doesn't hurt to ask. The worst thing that'll happen is they'll say it's not serial voting... Generally when moderators have to get involved, the user will receive a message explaining that the behavior is inappropriate, which will usually stop it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203530/234193 Have a look at this anwer.. it should probably be a question, but i am not sure there's a solution

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they can continue to cast downvotes. Just flag for moderator attention if you see repeated cycles of serial voting, if a user doesn't stop they'll get suspended.

The voting script is only the very first line of defense, after that it is mostly individual actions by moderators.

Comment: I think some people slip through the serial voting script. As my serial voting was only reversed by contacting the community team, as the person was doing it by stealth a couple a day.