# Can you tell why these downvotes are for?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

I have asked 6 questions, of which one is closed. Some of them had gotten upvotes, some downvotes. Yesterday somebody downvoted five of them. I can't see any reason why.

[Detect mouse scroll actions jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323380/detect-mouse-scroll-actions-jquery) `@ 14:19`
[Cut a string in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512887/cut-a-string-in-a-string) `@ 14:18`
[Permission denied when opening localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596020/permission-denied-when-opening-localhost) `@ 14:18`
[z-index issue CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462602/z-index-issue-css) `@ 14:18`
[jQuery UI switchClass() not working perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307134/jquery-ui-switchclass-not-working-perfectly) `@ 14:17`

Even stranger, this morning--just 5 min ago--someone *undownvoted* three of them.

Can anyone say why all this happened?

Comment: The users of Stack Overflow are incapable of long-range telepathy or clairvoyance. Therefore, we cannot know what the person who downvoted your questions was thinking. Even assuming that it was one person who did so.

Comment: I've edited 4 of them (doorknob took care of the other).  Please don't use 'Thanks' lines in your questions. Good luck.

Comment: @NicolBolas if there is an option to know what is the reason for downvote would be awesome. So posts can be made better.

Comment: @Harikrishnan: If someone doesn't want to tell you why they downvoted, they don't have to. Just move on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

People downvote for mysterious reasons.  Sometimes no reason at all.  If a computer decides that they seem be downvoting because it's something you posted (serial downvotes), the votes will be reversed by an automated script.

In the end, it's best to accept that some things in the world are simply unknowable and to not ponder them too deeply.

Comment: I dont understand why my questions are downvoted serially. All 5 questions are downvoted.

Comment: A marvelously zen answer.

Comment: @Harikrishnan: In this case it was very clearly serial downvoting since they all took place within a minute. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting) for more information. (Basically, you should give it some more time for the automatic script to detect and reverse it, and if it doesn't, contact the StackOverflow team using the Contact Us link).

Comment: @DavidRobinson thanks for the information.