# Victim of Serial Downvoting

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes, serial-voting

I got a series of down votes some-days (16 Aug 2013) before (Serial down-voting). I downvoted an answer and added a comment why I down-voted. After that I got too many down-votes for my different questions and answers within a minute.

**What I did:**

1. I checked this post on meta [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial down-voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting) and waited for 36 Hours. Nothing happened
2. I posted a comment on http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=1487443#1487443
3. I [flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1104384) one of my answer for moderator attention, currently the flag is in helpful state.

Nothing happened till now. It's almost 4 days passed after the serial down-voting.
What to do next? Do I need to send an email to the Stack Exchange team?

Comment: Don't call out names here, no matter the reason.

Comment: I vote to delete that fella, clearly he took offense because he was incapable of understanding what you were saying. Some people are just dicks, can't be helped, you got unlucky

Comment: By "that fella", do you mean [his downvoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267605/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-unable-to-presentviewcontroller/18267689#18267689), @musefan? I don't think he should delete it. The asker obviously found it useful.

Comment: @CodyGray: I mean iPatel as "that fella", his name has been edited out of this question now. That's why I said "that fella", but since you asked..

Comment: How do you and Midhun know it was him? Downvotes are anonymous. It could have been me for all you know.

Comment: @CodyGray: Investigate the situation, apply some logic, go with the most likely culprit. Downvotes are generally anonymous, but sometimes you just know

Comment: No, you don't! This is not based on "logic", it's just a guess. All you're doing is making wild accusations. If you're wrong, *you're* the one that is a dick.

Comment: @musefan And yet you can't prove it. That's why we have moderators or the team handle it. Leave it (and any necessary decision or action) up to them. As a regular user you simply move on.

Comment: @Bart, I don't intend or even have the ability to take any action or make a decision

Comment: @CodyGray Euhm, you seem to be ignoring the obvious. Don't do that, it makes you look illiterate.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oh, and iPatel has done this to me too. It's not the first time.

Comment: @CodyGray: No I don't sometimes just know? Of course I do, for example when somebody says "-1...". The fella was getting aggressive, he wanted to take out some revenge, lets just all agree we can be thankful him and MidhunMP were not in the same room at that time, who knows what could have broken out!

Comment: @H2CO3 Obvious isnt enough when you have take binding decisions. You need to be sure, which requires evidence, not accusations.

Comment: @AsheeshR You want evidence? Just look at OP's [reputation changes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1104384/midhun-mp?tab=reputation&StartDate=2013-08-16).

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm not saying he didn't receive serial downvotes. We're talking about blaming a particular user. Where in his reputation changes do you see "downvote by iPatel"?

Comment: @CodyGray [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193973/victim-of-serial-downvoting/193974?noredirect=1#comment608814_193973)

Comment: I don't know, I probably should stop replying now since I'm getting angry. I don't like being called illiterate. Especially when there is nothing to miss. There is nothing "obvious" here to ignore, @H2CO3.

Comment: @H2CO3 ...which is what the team will look at when they get to it. I dont see whats the point of arguing here when the team has [**obviously** been notified](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1487503#1487503).

Comment: @H2CO3 I totally disagree. Conspiracy theories have no place in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Nor does logic, apparently.

Comment: @H2CO3 sorry you feel this way.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, there **is** the obvious, and you still ignore it. OK, I don't (and didn't) call you illiterate. But there's no way you are accepting my opinion, so it's also pointless for me to continue arguing as well.

Comment: Arguments will go on as long as they have to. If you want to cut an argument short, I find the best way is to just agree with me. All my friends know this, well technically I should say ex-friends

Comment: Huh. I was hoping to be pointed to what it was that was so obvious. Not simply another assertion that it is there. Oh well, time to go downvote some more posts.

Comment: Not in a serial fashion I hope @CodyGray? .....

Comment: It's almost like we need a chat function on this site or something....

Comment: @Bart I honestly hope not, but I don't assume he would do that anyway. He's better than giving revenge dowvotes.

Comment: @DuncanJones http://chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: My comment was rather tongue-in-cheek @H2CO3.

Comment: @Bart Whatever, disregard, sorry.

Comment: @H2CO3 I think you missed the sarcasm there :-)

Comment: @DuncanJones Apparently, for the second time within 3 minutes :P

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing you should do but move on. A moderator was notified. [He notified the appropriate people. And your flag was dismissed as helpful.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1487503#1487503) Later on, he told you [to just wait](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1487785#1487785).

If nothing further happens (something might still happen), it's because nothing needs to happen. Or there is nothing that you need to be informed of or involved in.

Comment: The first rule of vote club is you don't talk about vote club.

Comment: Looking at [his reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1104384/midhun-mp?tab=reputation&StartDate=2013-08-16) he was serially downvoted on 16th Aug, 2013. So the primary question is why are those votes still not reversed.

Comment: @hims056 Look at the timestamps. If those are truly serial downvotes, they were cast in a way that the system did not pick up. And then you get to a point where you have to ask, were they unfair serial downvotes? Or simply targeted but valid votes. In any case, there is nothing the OP has to do about this.

Comment: @Bart - Accept that the OP doesn't need to do anything. But the system really need to check those tactical serial voting too.

Comment: @Bart -1 "nothing needs to happen" is certainly wrong. The downvotes are **obviously** serial. I think MidhunMP needs to contact the developer team for further help.

Comment: @H2CO3 We don't have the evidence. They do. They have been notified. If there is anything that can or needs to be done, they will do it. He can contact them, but it will be pointless.

Comment: @H2CO3: "The downvotes are obviously serial." Quick question, if they are so obviously serial votes, why haven't they been reversed by now like all of the other serial voting activity on SO?

Comment: @Bart Pointless? Tell me, why, seriously? If the audit script hasn't done its job, then the developers should do something for sure.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby The system is not perfect. It just **can be fooled.** When this happened to me once, I've contacted the team, they confirmed that it was indeed serial downvoting and one of the developers reversed it manually.

Comment: @H2CO3 And who says they aren't? A moderator has confirmed he did pass the issue on. Why on earth should a regular user need any further contact than that? What is he going to do?

Comment: @Bart Demand justification?

Comment: Oh come on @H2CO3. 12 rep. Move on.

Comment: @Bart It's not about the rep. It's about the attitude.

Comment: @H2CO3 12. As [the moderator in question stated](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1487503#1487503) there were 6 downvotes from a user. And the team has been notified. And the OP was told to be patient. So, be patient and move on. Focus on more constructive issues.