# My past answers being downvoted out of revenge?

Tags: discussion, comments, down-votes

I've recently had a stream of downvotes without comment on a number of my answers. I personally feel these answers are of objectively good quality and I fear I am being targeted out of spite.

Could someone please investigate?

[Android Volley - Cancel NetworkImageView request in Base Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302831/android-volley-cancel-networkimageview-request-in-base-adapter/18342666#18342666)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149602/creating-a-table-layout-in-android/18149649#18149649

[getDeclaredFields() absolute performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395881/getdeclaredfields-absolute-performance)

[Running JavaScript within a Service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442093/running-javascript-within-a-service-in-android)

[How to get comment count from your wall posts without making a call to comments object for each post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800033/how-to-get-comment-count-from-your-wall-posts-without-making-a-call-to-comments)

[Volley ImageLoader really slow on older devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939229/volley-imageloader-really-slow-on-older-devices)

I'm not sure who it is but the only person I've gotten into a tif was recenlty on this question, where I felt the answer was misleading and didn't answer the question.

[How to perform Segue in AppDelegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305636/how-to-perform-segue-in-appdelegate/12305665#12305665)

Comment: I had the same experience check my post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193973/victim-of-serial-downvoting

Comment: Just flag one of your posts for moderator attention. If it is a single user serial voting on your posts, it's not of the type that will be automatically reversed. A moderator might be able to investigate or pass the message on to those capable of doing so.

Comment: No need to flag now (but do so in the future). We are investigating.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: In this case there's no evidence of serial down-voting and there's no definitive evidence of targeted voting against you. sorry, but there's nothing we can do at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for investigating Chris. I appreciate that there is nothing definitive even though it might be unusual (ie downvotes on popular/upvoted answers and timing). Is it fair to ask if this is one or multiple down voters?

Comment: It's probable that it's multiple people because if it were only one it *would* be serial downvoting.

Comment: @Pork Multiple people... **or revenge-downvoter sockpuppets?**

Comment: *"If you want in appdelegate, than bring references there." <- you need to show this.* You need to stop telling people what to do in comments.  If someone provides an answer which generally guides the asker in the correct direction, that is completely acceptable.  It is not your responsibility to tell them that their answer is incomplete, and not your right to judge what constitutes a complete answer.  If you don't like an answer, simply downvote it and move on.  You lecture someone in comments (oh, the irony), you shouldn't complain when they react negatively.

Comment: I understand reacting negatively. But there is a difference between reacting negatively and down voting objectively good discourse in unrelated questions.

Sadly, I think because of this incident I'm probably going to participate less on stackoverflow.