# Preventing hate downvote

Tags: support

I just been victimized by a user for hate downvote. The story is like this: I reply to one question, and realise that someone suggested an off-topic answer, I downvote him and comment about the downvote.

After 10 minutes, I check back on Stack Overflow, and I realise that all my past comments and questions start getting downvoted. I lose about 20 points due to those downvotes. I accept that someone can downvote me, if they don't like my answer, but in 5-10 minutes 20-30 comments of mine from 6 month old question/comments get downvotes which means someone is doing it on purpose.

Comment: Some people have bad days... About your rep it might get back since all  downvotes were serial. But notify a mod and wait.

Comment: [That's quite the enemy you've got there](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1160395/sumit-gupta?tab=reputation). Wait a day. Those downvotes will get noticed by automated detection scripts, and rolled back.

Comment: Yeah, don't worry. That will automatically be reversed. There are systems in place to detect and handle this. Just move on from the situation.

Comment: I am idiot I should search about it first in here, anyways, thanks for information, I just thought to let moderator know, not sure what is correct method to do so create a thread. I already moved on...

Comment: You do that by flagging one of your affected posts.

Comment: @BoltClock, is [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting/28758#28758) still correct, which says to wait for 36 hours before flagging for moderator attention?

Comment: While you *should* be able to say why you down voted without being revenge downvoted I often find it helpful to separate the downvote and the comment; I.e.rather than saying "I down voted because XYZ" just say "I think XYZ". Its still pretty obvious you downvoted but the lack of certainty avoids a lot of revenge

Comment: And when I agree with such comment @Richard suggested, then I make sure to upvote the comment, regardless if I downvote the post myself or not. (Especially when I *do* downvote, and am the first to do so, and see that someone else already left a comment without downvoting themselves. Seeing that comment upvoted, the author knows there's somebody else who might have downvoted instead of the one who commented.)

Comment: @Richard Tingle: You would be amazed how wrong your last sentence is on both accounts.

Comment: @Arjan: I don't know about flagging actually, considering we can warn the culprit at any time if we do find evidence of serial voting.

Comment: Just to say it all, comments cannot be down-voted. Only answers and questions (a.k.a. the posts) can be down-voted.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I think that the OP said `comments` and meant `answers`. (I *think*. I'm not 100% sure.)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I didn't understand what you meant before, [I do now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195966/banned-for-speaking-the-truth)

Comment: @Richard Tingle: Ugh, sorry that you learned it the hard way :/