# When does serial down voting script run?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I just got serial downvoted, and I suspect it's [my "nemesis"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573032/roman-c).

When do the scripts run, and would this instance be detected?

It also looks like someone serial un-upvoted said nemesis, which is also poor behavior, as much as I dislike the guy. Is that detected as well?

Comment: every 24 hours.

Comment: You should have added this http://stackoverflow.com/users/573032/roman-c?tab=reputation

Comment: @hims056 I don't think it as duplicate.  Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/users/573032/roman-c?tab=reputation

Comment: [03:00 GMT](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144478/165773)... but don't tell anyone! it's a secret

Comment: @user1671639 - The question is: "When does serial downvoting script run?"

Comment: Yeah... this is all pretty messed up. The users involved have been suspended.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn An unfortunate turn of events. While my issues with RomanC are fairly public and I've called for action, and I'm not psyched about the other's reaction, I understand it.

Comment: The script runs every [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/238586).