# Informing/dealing with invalid-edit'ers

Tags: support, user-accounts, tag-abuse

User in question is [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573032/roman-c?tab=activity&sort=revisions)

When I was checking SO meta, I come across with [that Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199944/when-does-serial-down-voting-script-run) As I check the user history, I see many (many) 1 character edits, *a single whitespace character somewhere in the text, generally at the end*

Revision history is 115 page long and it is hard to undone all invalid edits. Probably he is a badge hunter. How can I report this user directly?

Comment: As always, flagging one of the user's posts for moderator attention and described the situation in the custom field is probably the easiest way to report it.

Comment: Yet more fun with this user >:| How many times does a user have to be discussed on meta before something longer-lasting is done? This doesn't even include his (at least one) sock puppet.

Comment: And how is it that single-character whitespace edits were accepted anyway, I thought there was a minimum?

Comment: @DaveNewton There's no minimum for users above the edit threshold (2000 on SO, I believe). The minimum only applies to *suggested* edits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, just flag one of the posts that was edited with the "needs moderator attention" flag and explain the problematic pattern. A moderator will deal with it. There is also no need to roll back, as the edits don't do anything, undoing a non-edit would just add more noise to the revision history.

In this case this is not necessary, the mods are already aware of it.

Comment: I think we posted our comments/answers as the *exact* same time, according to the tooltip timestamps. +1!