# Continuously voting down

Tags: support, stack-overflow, down-votes

Some one is showing his conservative and little thinking by voting down all of my questions & answers on Stack Overflow. Here is the snap shot of my reputation changes:

[image: screenshot of serial down votes]

You can also visit my profile and see this by yourself. I know the person who is doing this to me.

How can I stop them from doing this?

Comment: It is called serial downvoting. And yes, this has been asked many times before. See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28758/220538) some useful suggestions.

Comment: This will be corrected automatically at the end of the day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's called serial voting, and it is completely unacceptable on SO. However, the devs have created a process to find out when this occurs, and it will be reversed. If, however, it is not reversed in the next 36 hours, flag one of your downvoted posts for mod attention, and leave them a message asking them to reverse it manually

Comment: Waiting to get my reputation back :)

Comment: Got it back !! :)