# What happens to a serial downvoter reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, serial-voting

I have seen [what happens to a serial downvoter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279082/what-happens-to-a-serial-downvoter), but I have some "follow on" questions:

- I saw my top 3 answers downvoted yesterday, and the system decided that this was "serial downvoting" - reputation restored today. Now I am wondering: will the *downvoter* get back his 3 points as well? Or are they not coming back?
- Is any of this "visible" on the "activity/reputation" page of another user? Meaning: would those -3 and +3 show up there?

Comment: As far as I know, the votes are simple removed, as if they never happened. I'm sure they get the rep back, but not sure if it's visible anywhere.

Comment: @ShadowWizard All rep gains will be shown as a green box. Except that you won't see any highlighted item if it's a removal of a rep loss event.

Comment: @iBug thing is, that isn't rep gain. It is as if the vote never existed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The notification treats *any* rep incr. as gain.

Comment: Although you don't see the +3 in their rep history (according to the answers and my own memory) you'll still can use that info if you already had someone in mind and know their previous reputation points and if they got +3 today. That still is 100% since they may got them from other downvotes, it is still a strong indicator.

Comment: @Tom Sure. But as you said: A) you need somebody to check on ... and you B) need to know their previous reputation ... on a good day, I review 20 to 40 posts from queues, and I often give comments; put another 20 on top of that that I just notice and vote/comment. And I have seen serial downvotes for a close request "off topic here, please turn to codereview" ... whereas I got back "I see, thanks" for comments were I, myself thought "uuh, maybe I was too harsh here". Meaning: it is even hard to determine which accounts to check on. So playing "detective" isnt a real option ...

Comment: Yes, you already need clue, if you don't have that one, then there isn't much you can do, except for hoping that the reversal script kicks in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Yes**. Downvoters will get their rep back
2. **No.** They'll have a green `+x` notification on their achivements box, but that's only visible to themselves. No one else sees their DV history (as it's revoked)

The system mechanics has no extra punishment or penalty to serial downvoters. Nothing is done automatially except the forced reversal of serial DV actions. They will simply see a green box with `+3` and see no highlighted events, as when normal action reversals occur.

The first paragraph of the accepted answer to the question you linked to reads:

> There are **no automated penalties** beyond the reversal of the votes, but moderators can take action.

If a user performs serial DV repeatedly, mods will be informed and often step in to manually apply punishments. That's all up the mods. This isn't what you're asking because it's not done by the system (or computers) so it doesn't affect the answer.

Looks like someone targeted me. I believe he's for testing purposes. I will update this part when I see the DVs are revoked (by the system).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That `+3` is kind of saying that - "Hey downvoter, the system recognized that you have serially downvoted someone. (Now take care next time and do it slowly so that the system doesn't recognize.)"

Comment: @JaideepKhare I guess that is a different discussion; but I basically agree. It probably depends on how *accurate* the underlying algorithm is. Assume that this algorithm puts up a penalty (not only not giving back the -3, but maybe multiply that by 10 or more) - and does that automatically. I guess that might mean a lot of work for moderators because many people would start flagging that and claim that this wasnt serial downvoting). And for the record: I once asked about serial downvoting and was told that 3 incidents would never account for that.

Comment: The question is _Whether the downvoter get back his 3 rep(lost while downvoting 3 answer) or not_ and you are not discussing about it

Comment: @SagarV Extracted answer and put it top

Answer (score 1):

> will the downvoter get back his 3 points as well? Or are they not coming back?

They will get it.

If the serial voting is reversed, both the targetted person and the downvoter get the rep back.

> Is any of this "visible" on the "activity/reputation" page of another user? Meaning: would those -3 and +3 show up there?

No. The *-1* for downvoting and also the reversal votes will not be shown by others.

FYI the voting reversal will not shown publicly in both profiles. That is both target person and downvoter.

For example, I was targetted day before yesterday and the votes are reversed yesterday.

The seriel votes are shown but the reversal will not shown when another person checking my profile(except a diamond user).

This is the info another person see in my rep history. He can see the downvotes but can't see the reversal.

[image]

Comment: which page ?  ??

Comment: Sorry for stupid question. I turned on my computer and found it,

Comment: it's the activity page