# Multi downvote on my answers

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes

I have recently received several down-votes to my questions/answers at the same time on StackOverflow. I don't think it was done accidently, but was a targeted attack against me. Though I have no idea who could do that and why. I know that there is no way I can see who did that and I don't seek truth here. But I just wonder if there is some moderation tool that sees such kind of attacks i.e. many down votes coming on the same user for answers belonging to completely different tags.

8m
1
-2
    turn off soap extension on webmethod

8m
1
-2
    Requirements for HTTPS URl connection using Glassfish

8m
1
-2
    Best option for Session management in Java

41m
1
-2
    Simulation of long-running Oracle DB query

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes

Comment: +1 Users don't have the manual, and if they did, they wouldn't read it. In fact, users can't read anything, and if they could, they wouldn't want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a daily script that detects the "chain hate downvote pattern" and corrects it every night.

If the downvotes are still there tomorrow, I think you can contact team@stackoverflow.com and ask them to look into it. Or flag one for moderator attention and explain your issue.

Comment: this also applies to "chain love upvote patterns" :)

Comment: "There's a daily script that ... corrects it every night." Wouldn't that be a nightly script then? ;-)

Comment: @fretje, it depends on your timezone.