# Combatting Mass-Downvoting

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Mysterious downvotes (14 random downvotes in 5 minutes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes)
>   [Serial Downvoting Victim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim)

So....

Dude gets mad at me. Goes to my profile. Looks at my last 5-10 questions and downvotes them all just because.

Any method for stopping this or just live with it? I'm perfectly fine living with it, just doesn't seem right.

Comment: The fraud script will undo them.

Comment: Could you explain this 'fraud' script? I've been on here awhile, never really heard of it.

Comment: A script which runs automatically and detects vote frauds. Just wait.

Comment: Wow, looks like he took offense at your comment on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34409/what-is-the-best-way-to-gain-high-reputation-on-so -- how so very petty.

Comment: see jeff's comments here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim/28758#28758

Comment: Has this issue already been corrected? I ask because as of now I don't see any serial downvotes against you here on Meta.

Comment: @Æther you're not a mod, how do you know it was that user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag one of these posts for moderator attention and explain the situation. However, there are heuristics in place to detect and reverse this, so it may be reversed automatically sometime later today.

For more information (and earlier incidents) see:

- [I was just attacked by an onslaught of downvotes! What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes)
- [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim)
- [Multi downvote on my answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29092/multi-downvote-on-my-answers)
- [Preventing users from downvoting good answers to bad questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23005/i-think-i-was-just-serial-downvoted-how-can-this-prevented-by-the-community)
- [What to do about mass down votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22346/what-to-do-about-mass-down-votes-closed)