# One User Going to My Answers And Down Voting - Down-Voting Bomb?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

I just got 3 downvotes in a row on 3 of my recent answers.  I also just asked a question, got 2 bad (IMO) answers and downvoted those answers.  Coincidence?  I think not.

I have since went back and took away the downvotes I gave to the 2 answers, and now the downvotes on my 3 answers have been taken back too.  Can SO do anything about people like this who downvote bomb you?

Comment: There are already some measures in place against "downvote bombing" -- we usually call it "tactical downvoting" here -- but they might not have helped in this case. If you suspect bombing, flag one of the downvoted posts for mod attention and enter a short description. Your question text here would work just fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combatting Mass-Downvoting.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34420/combatting-mass-downvoting)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysterious downvotes (14 random downvotes in 5 minutes)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since 3 downvotes is most likely not enough to trigger the downvote protection mechanism* you should flag a post - any post - for moderator attention, so they can look into it.

<sup>* When I did some testing on a dummy SE 1.0 website I found out that the mechanism kicked in after 5 or more downvotes in 1 day from the same user.</sup>