# Repeated downvotes on my posts

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, voting, down-votes

Yesterday someone started downvoting my answers. I ignored the downvotes knowing that the system will reverse them, and the system did reverse some of those downvotes.

Today I flagged one of my answers, chose *in need of moderator intervention*, and explained my problem. I stated who it was. since I know who it is, then few hours later, the downvotes came again.

What should I do in this case, since this person keeps coming again and again? And from now on, how will I know if the downvote against my answer is a legit downvote not someone just against me?

#### Downvotes from Yesterday

[image: repeated down votes]

#### Downvotes from Today

[image: downvotes]

Comment: Specifically, casting a moderator flag like you did is the right thing to do. See the very last section of the linked question.

Comment: so if the user doesn't mass downvotes, because they know the system will detect their actions, and choose to down vote on one of my answers each day, what should I do or how will the system handle this type of behaviour?

Comment: Just as you did: flag it when you see it again. E.g., in your downvotes today, both were cast in the same minute; flag one of them, for mod attention, and mention the other, and refer to your previous related flag(s) ...  On some sites, mods have an "office"-chat, where you can engage moderators.  And on some sites, you can request to have a private chat.  Importantly, though one might be very tempted to downvote posts from the user you suspect, as "punishment", refrain from doing so .... That can be very difficult to do, but try not to stoop to the offenders level of behavior.

Comment: I just got two more down votes, but now I don't even know if they are legit down votes or they are from the same person.

Comment: @Junius  If they were both cast withing one or two minutes of each other, one is worth flagging for mod attention (mentioning previously flagged downvotes and the additional downvote.  That's the problem: SE thinks it handles all examples of malicious downvoting; in reality, it only can detect a massive downvoting within one a few minutes, and justifiably revert those votes.  But they haven't the intelligence, commitment, and/or skill to detect ongoing downvotes, and the ongoing downvotes that go under the radar of the blantant downvoting scripts are the most malicious of downvoting.

Comment: @Junius  I'd also suggest you edit your question to include your question posted as a comment.  If you do that, this question may be reopened, becaus it's clear, this site has not adequate question/answer dealing with prolonged trickles of downvotes from a single user for days, even weeks.

Answer (score -1):

The Stack Exchange network of websites has heuristics in place to curb mass (up/down)votes. If detected, they are reversed and offending account may also get banned/deleted.

While mass upvotes are more common (using dummy accounts or by asking friends/acquaintances), mass downvoting, especially on answers is limited as the downvotes also suffers a penalty by losing 1 rep point.

You can refer to the following post for more details:

- [Combatting Mass-Downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34420/combatting-mass-downvoting)

Comment: Unfortunately, the heuristics (or at least the serial voting detection scripts) do not detect a single user's one to two downvotes a day, done daily for weeks.  To deal with this phenomenon, the victim needs to do exactly what the OP has done: flag for moderator attention.  And if necessary, continue to do so each day it happens.