# Badge suggestion: Zealot (got 3 questions with at least 10 downvotes each)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, badge-request, negative-badges

Or maybe some other variation of that, like "20 downvotes anywhere within 1 day". Probably it should be bronze regardless.

It seems like there's a [script running](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes/21576#21576) against this badge, but that'd be fine. It's just for fun anyway. :D

Well, maybe it will be an incentive for most not getting that. I don't know.

**edit:** What about this other perspective - out of over 40 badges, all for "good behavior" none is actually "awarded" for "bad behavior". So, having at least 1 could give us a better idea of how people are behaving in the "bad manner". As for how people would actually react to that, I say that guessing here is pure speculation.

Comment: Who would *want* to receive this badge?

Comment: @Jon I don't know. But it sure could work as a reminder - you're doing bad! :o

Comment: People who don't give a rat's *ahem* about rep don't give one about badges either.

Comment: @squillman well, someone had to ask it. Now we know for sure the community does not welcome this kind of humor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to analyze the bad behaviors on the site, the data from each of the SOFU sites is available in the [monthly data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/).  Download it and analyze to your hearts content.

As has already been mentioned, badges are to encourage behaviors.  Having a badge that rewards a negative behavior would only encourage members to exhibit the negative behavior.  Upstanding and respected users on the sites would be forced to ask bad questions, just so they can say they have **all** the badges. Definitely not a good idea!

Comment: Accepting this because of the monthly data dump **link**. But the suggestion was not just for analysis and the data dump wouldn't be nearly as simple and easy to check as the badge for this specific data point.

Comment: @Cawas, again, badges are not data points used for analysis.  They are just a part of the game we are all playing.  Their sole purpose is to promote behaviors that are wanted on the site.

Comment: ok, but that doesn't mean things can't change. Maybe making "bad moody badges" to encourage not getting them? I just enjoy some dark humor.

Comment: Asking the highest ranking members to ask ridiculous questions can be fun for lower ranking guys. THe questions split our brains as we try to duct tape a meaning to the conflicting vague statements. Net result for the young guy, "Damn I just learned a lot about something, even thogh I don't know why what it was.

Answer (score 17):

This would encourage bad behavior, so it won't get implemented.

Jeff's always saying that badges are there to encourage specific actions, so I doubt they'll put a badge "just for fun", let alone one that would make people post horrible posts in order to get downvotes.

Comment: "Tumbleweed" is just for fun, isn't it?

Comment: @Bruno: Yes, but you still have to ask a valid question for it to survive that long.

Comment: Also, do people write terrible posts just to get "Peer Pressure"? But I do disagree with the suggested badge anyway.

Comment: I think it would be mostly for meta anyway.

Comment: @Cawas, but badges are not limited to a single site, you have to suggest something that'd work on all

Comment: @Downvoter oh, then I got that one wrong! :P   I'm not sure how that'd work elsewhere, but I think it would just not be ever awarded elsewhere.

Comment: @Bruno: For Peer Pressure, certainly, one could write bad posts on purpose. The thing is, there are few "fun" badges, so if someone wants them, go ahead, they'll run out very quickly. To get a ton of badges, the bottom line is that you have to post above-average content, which is, overall, a positive encouragement.

Comment: I should also add that one can receive a Peer Pressure badge simply by giving an answer that the author believes to be correct, but that the community doesn't believe to be correct. This, I think, was both the purpose of the badge, and also where the name for it came from.

Comment: I think so too @Jon

Comment: @Juan so you're not the @downvoter any longer! What went wrong with the whole world? (i.e. why did you change it?)

Answer (score 2):

Yah but there would always be the people that would then engage in negative behavior just to get the badge. Remember, negative attention is *still* attention.

Comment: I'm not sure why people try to negate so much the negative does exist and is just another needed part of life.

Comment: Not sure if sentence.

Answer (score 2):

**No.** Badges should be a reward for good things.

I don't like the existing Tumbleweed and Peer Pressure badges. (Even though it's questionable if Peer Pressure is really negative as you can also think of it as a reward for taking the time to delete a bad post).

Comment: I don't think tumbleweed is bad either. If you have a question that can't be answered you may only know it after trying.