# Badge for low score?

Tags: support, badges

My question, [Code Golf: Write an Stackoverflow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465308/code-golf-write-an-stackoverflow-clone-closed) is currently sitting at -14 votes.

Do I get a badge of some sort for this?

Comment: Loser badge ? :)

Comment: You have asked 200+ questions and still haven't learn where to ask questions? This belongs to meta.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42056/badge-suggestion-zealot-got-3-questions-with-at-least-10-downvotes-each

Answer (score 3):

You'll get a badge if you *delete* a posting with a score of -3 or less. Not sure if it works for CW posts, though.

Comment: Hmm... HINT HINT! :)

Comment: @Jeff: damn, and here I was going to open source my clone...

Answer (score 3):

Badges are given out to encourage certain types of behavior that are considered "good" in some way or the other.

If a question receives 15 downvotes and no upvotes, chances are pretty high that it's a bad question. Posting bad questions is not considered good behavior, so there's no badge for that.

<sub>On a side note, I've been having the idea in my head for quite a while to post this very code golf question. If you do something like that, you have to provide exact specs. In this case, either a REST API that is specified, or input/output of a CGI script, or something like that. CGI would probably be the best, meaning there's no network cruft to worry about. You'd also have to specify exactly what kinds of thing you should be able to do with the app, and provide sample input/output data, and more. Running a good code golf isn't just jotting down 2 1/2 sentences and then going home. I have myself run a pretty successful (in terms of how it was received by the community) code golf, and I assure you it was quite some work.</sub>