# Serial downvote record-holder

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

I just got 11 downvotes on SO in the space of three minutes. Is this a record? Note that to compete for the record, the downvotes must all be on different answers/questions.

One thing I don't get about the people who do this is their motivation. They probably don't know that the votes will be rolled back, but do they really think that -22 rep points are going to make me go off and cry in a corner?

Comment: may be they waiting your post in meta and celebrating now. :)

Comment: It made you come here and ask a question... Downvotes are annoying, especially if they're senseless downvotes to good questions/answers. You might not care about the rep, but you still don't like the votes; I sure don't!

Comment: @alex Serial downvotes I don't really mind, and in fact find a bit amusing, hence this post. I do kind of object to having technically correct answers downvoted for no reason though, in which case I usually make a comment to the answer on SO, not post here.

Comment: may be someone envy you on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853322) +11 voted post and did -11 on your other question?

Comment: Has the topic of those posts recently been updated, perhaps all 11 simultaneously became out of date?? lol.

Comment: An apparently correct answer of mine picked up -3. Since it's one of those rare moments when I actually knew what I was talking about, I wonder Neil's experience is part of some wider spree.

Comment: In less than 3 mins I got 7 downvotes is this weird? this was on a different account

Comment: I just lost 56 reputation points due to serial-downvoting, and I am sure we can find worse.

Answer (score 21):

42!* And possibly still ongoing. Originating from somewhere around [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977997/from-where-do-i-get-this-type-of-images-like-this-awesome-website) which, for the record, I did not even downvote.

Some people have too much time on their hands. :)

---

* Yes, seriously, *42*. I think I can die happy now. X-D

http://phpcode.eu/images/1312792286.png

Comment: I think we have a winner

Comment: You should earn a badge-something to the effect of Troll Magnet

Comment: [42 is the answer!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236182/what-is-the-origin-of-magic-number-42-indispensable-in-coding)

Answer (score 8):

The worst I ever got was 18, I think it was the result of closing the n'th attempt of someone re-posting the same exact question because they did not like the answers they received on the last attempt.

One of the other closers had *just* reached 10k and happened to be in IRC at the time. He was rather upset that someone else's hissy fit ruined his "I just reached 10k" party.

Fortunately, it was close to the time that the serial down-vote checker ran, all was back to normal within an hour.

Just be glad you don't have a SO stalker that serially up/down votes every single thing you post.

I feel that this is solid evidence that having a life is not a prerequisite for living.

Comment: Stack Overthrow takes your life by force.

Answer (score 6):

No, they didn't break the record, at least to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes) one

Comment: I will have to try harder, I guess.

Answer (score 6):

I just got 30 downvotes (which I guess is due to serial downvoting), which reminded me of this thread.

Glad I didn't give my address.

Comment: I think we have a winner.

Answer (score 2):

No, I got 14 down votes in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94454/will-the-removal-of-reputation-cost-when-down-voting-questions-encourage-users-to)

[image]

I still think that removal of reputation cost when down voting questions will encourage users to down vote indiscriminately. I have posted this issue in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94454/will-the-removal-of-reputation-cost-when-down-voting-questions-encourage-users-to), But no one agree with me.

Comment: **I** agree with you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just got [28](https://stackoverflow.com/users/659804/ernest-friedman-hill?tab=reputation), and I have *no idea* who I might have angered, or how.

Comment: Damn son, somebody's out to get you.

Comment: Hey, now I'm getting random *upvotes*. I love you guys :)

Comment: You'll get it all back tomorrow, and likely lose some of the upvotes due to the same script. *The Vote Fraud Script giveth and the Vote Fraud Script taketh away.*

Comment: They've been reversed, within ~3 hours. Gotta love that.