# I feel I am being voted down on multiple posts without any apparent reason!

Tags: support, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial Downvoting Victim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim)

I get a feeling that my posts have been targeted by a particular user and voted down without any apparent reason! I come back online today to find that 5 of my posts have been voted down within a minute, so it's a little hard to believe that it's because my questions are frivolous! Is there any way we could find out and block the person who is doing such an activity from visiting our profile? It's just that it's really hard to earn rep which I need to start a bounty and when I see my posts voted down for no apparent reason, it just annoys me!

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50304/serial-downvote-record http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23005/i-think-i-was-just-serial-downvoted-how-can-this-prevented-by-the-community

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a background job to detect such serial downvotes. If it recognizes this as a series, it will undo the downvotes and reassign the reputation. It works for serial upvotes as well.

The detection algorithm, for good reasons, is not public. Otherwise malicious downvoters would game it easily. I would expect a minimum of rules like this: downvotes are from the same person, there are more than a certain number with a certain time frame.

You can always have a moderator look at it. Flag one of the posts for moderator attention and point to the other posts in question. A moderator could do a recalc as well to have your rep recalculated if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that! Really bothers me that he has not left a comment either!