# Someone is down voting me

Tags: support, reputation, abuse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysterious downvotes (14 random downvotes in 5 minutes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes)

Yesterday I down voted someone in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059322/admob-orientation-problem-in-android/3223764#3223764) question.

Afterwards I got down votes to my answer in that question and in:

- [quickactions-like-the-twitter-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957860/quickactions-like-the-twitter-app)
- [initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line)

which are two of my questions with more up votes. And without comments explaining why.

What can/should I do in this case?

Comment: Many dupes for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Serial down-voting can (and is) detected automatically, but requires more than D down-votes in less than M minutes from the same person where "D" and "M" are unknown to anyone outside Stack Overflow.

Unfortunately 2 or 3 down-votes probably won't trigger the system. If you think they were unfair then flag one of the posts as Lance suggests.

Otherwise just accept it as part of life on Stack Overflow and move on.

Comment: It takes 5 votes before even moderators can see it.

Comment: @mmyers - thanks for clarifying that. I did have 5 in the back of my mind, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 3):

Flag for Moderator Attention, and explain your dilemma.

Comment: if only life was that easy...