# Detecting trolls and enemies :P

Tags: support, stack-overflow, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysterious downvotes (14 random downvotes in 5 minutes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes)

Someone has downvoted a few of my answers(which I think are my favourite answers) one after the other without giving any reason/comment.

[image]

How to detect such trolls/enemies? Is it even possible?

Comment: The system will revert them automatically at the end of the day if there is too strong a pattern. Don't worry too much about it.

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/ and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/

Comment: Thats nothing. I had guys flag 9 of my questions multiple times causing me to lose 900points in a single day. I emailed the admins, they seem to not want to touch it. Consider yourself lucky if its an obvious troll and he only does downvotes.

Comment: I lost nearly 300 points. :(

Comment: @Prasoon - You had nearly 150 downvotes then?

Comment: @acid, that's a huge drop [in January](http://stackoverflow.com/users/34537?tab=reputationhistory) indeed. But it takes, I think, 6 red flags and hence 6 different accounts to get a post banned. So, did team@stackoverflow really not give any insight about those flags being appropriate? It's not just the reputation; the questions and its answers have been deleted as well, so I guess you and the answerers deserve some explanation. **But it seems all your flagged questions were quite subjective, and hence plain off-topic?**

Answer (score 2):

Just like in real life, sometimes you (unintentionally) do something that irritates other people. Most of the time, they complain once and go on with their life. But a small percentage of them wants revenge. And on SO and sister sites, downvoting and question closing can be used as revenge. But this mechanism isn't very effective. First every down vote cost only 2 rep and the revenger loses 1. Second the system detects if person A downvotes person B a lot and takes measures against it. Multiple accounts are also detectabele so the system is rather fair.

I can advice you to ignore the downvotes, or to send a mail to the team. Because public complaints can backfire.

In the end we just want a great resource for programmers.