# Someone decided to downvote 23 of my answers for no apparent reason

Tags: discussion, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysterious downvotes (14 random downvotes in 5 minutes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes)

Someone decided to check my profile and downvote every answer time would permit (23 of them).

Is this something popular?

Recently I checked a post on hacker news about a question about why we use i,j on counters. I realised I posted an identical question a few years ago and asked to close the question as an exact duplicate. Now I get that the new answer is superior to the answer I accepted, but I don't think it justifies a personnal vendetta.

Clearly I'm not getting downvoted for the quality of my answers but for a single action stackoverflow encourrages me to do, close duplicate questions.

There is nothing to gain from maintaining the website other than risking morons exposure.

Comment: Never mind. The downvotes will be gone tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Read the comments

apparently there is a magical script that takes care of such events

A more detailed discussion is in [an identical question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes)