# Sudden flood of downvotes

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysterious downvotes (14 random downvotes in 5 minutes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes)

I just logged in to my Stack Overflow account that my reputation has gone down by an amount it shouldn't. I checked the history and it seems, somehow all my questions till now have been downvoted by `-2`, about 2 hours ago. I don't have any idea how it happened. Here is a screenshot of the history.

[image]

I hope this is the place to ask this. I tried `SO Tavern` chat room, but the room is deserted right now..

Comment: See here please: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes

Comment: No need to worry. If the downvoters are indeed suspicious (i.e., all cast by the same user in a relatively short period of time), an automated process will remove them and restore your rep to its previous level. Give it some time to work, though; it doesn't run all the time.

Comment: @Juan, @Cody Got it. Thanks. :)