# Maniacal Question Downvoting?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial downvotes in quick succession on all my posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/serial-downvotes-in-quick-succession-on-all-my-posts)

I just went to [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal?tab=reputation) about one minute ago and I noticed that someone (I really don't know who) down-voted a lot of my questions all within the span of about 10 minutes.

I know I will probably get back the reputation at some point, but for now I would like to know if someone could shed some light on who did the down-voting, and when had I come across this user to incur such a harsh response.

[image: screensot]

---

I just found the user: It was the OP of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363752/have-a-jsfiddle-you-want-to-share (the link is for 10k users).

Also, I now see it was the same user as one of my previous issues: [User revenge? All my questions were downvoted in the past hour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98500/user-revenge-all-my-questions-were-downvoted-in-the-past-hour).

Comment: Hmmm me too, see my post

Comment: @rickyduck -- i just did. It is very very odd.

Comment: See meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/92080/… and meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/21575/…  [Quoted from CanSpice] from my question.. oh well, thats life :)

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92080/sudden-flood-of-downvotes and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/serial-downvotes-in-quick-succession-on-all-my-posts

Comment: @CanSpice : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98500/user-revenge-all-my-questions-were-downvoted-in-the-past-hour

Comment: You closed a question, and the OP got upset (and downvoted everyone involved, until he ran out of votes for the day).

Comment: @TimStone -- yep, it seems to be this OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363752/have-a-jsfiddle-you-want-to-share

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid pointing fingers, but figured you'd get it. :P

Comment: @TimPost wow, now i see (since the accounts were merged) that it was the same user who did this before to me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98500/user-revenge-all-my-questions-were-downvoted-in-the-past-hour

Comment: Seems to me that a box is should be in the future of this perp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SE engine caters for behaviour like this, your rep will most likely be adjusted at the next re-calc.

[See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98500/user-revenge-all-my-questions-were-downvoted-in-the-past-hour/98510#98510).

Comment: @Dunhamzzzz haha that was my question that u linked to :-P

Comment: why isn't fraud detection included in recalc?