# Lots of downvotes?

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial downvotes in quick succession on all my posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/serial-downvotes-in-quick-succession-on-all-my-posts)

Suddenly, [someone downvoted all my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504299/rickyduck?tab=reputation).
Why would someone do this and isn't there some feature to stop this?

I think it may be due to my last activity (commenting on a poor question); all I did was offer advice.

Obviously it is an immature Stack Overflow member. Is there anything I can do to reinstate the reputation? I am not too fussed; if not, I just think it is a bit stupid.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92080/sudden-flood-of-downvotes and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/serial-downvotes-in-quick-succession-on-all-my-posts

Comment: it was this OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363752/have-a-jsfiddle-you-want-to-share

Comment: Yep, all I did was try and be nice :(

Comment: In this particular case, there was also a sock puppet helping to downvote. I've merged and suspended; if you recalc now, you might get some if not all of the points back.

Comment: It seems we both got hit byt he same guy.... u were nice. doesnt mean he will be....

Comment: @mmyers -- I was hit by the same puppet - also some of the other closers of that question.

Comment: @mmyers ! ha ! that was the same user i complained about a few months ago? wow....

Comment: @Neal - ErrorErrorError is the deleted name

Comment: @rickyDuck -- it is the same user that i complained about in july: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98500/user-revenge-all-my-questions-were-downvoted-in-the-past-hour

Comment: @Neal - I mean, ErrorErrorError wasn't his name, when he got deleted it was replaced with that

Comment: I know, he was known in july for making many many account. see my question.

Answer (score 3):

> Why would someone do this?

Because people are inherently naughty, all *good* acts just cover up the fact.

> Isn't there some feature to stop this?

Why, yes there is. But not so much prevention as it is detection. Down-voting can't be deemed as a *serial* case on a per down-vote basis - the system will analyse the voting "habits", should recognise the pattern and correct your "karma".

EDIT: Alternatively: come here, complain, get the satisfaction of seeing the user boxed off, evidently.

Comment: If there is a 24 hour "Fraud Detection", why not on an as is basis?

Comment: If there is a 24h "Fraud Detection", then why waste resources running it per vote? It's not like you've lost your wallet for the day and can't buy foodstuffs.

Comment: What resources would it though? However I guess if it was more efficient, SO would implement it

Comment: I don't know _exactly_ what resources, but suffice to say that when a system which normally "does stuff" does "more stuff" then it'll use more "fuel"; in this case we could even consider clock cycles.

Comment: For reasons that really should be obvious, no one's going to give you the exact details of the fraud detection algorithm @ricky. Think of it like writing a cheque - it *may* take up to three days to clear, but you should consider the money gone immediately.

Comment: Fair enough, points taken.

Comment: I remember when I was once serial-downvoted and my immediate thought was, "Really? Is this all this person can do to me for retaliation? Man, Stack Overflow is _great_. Anywhere else on the internet this would have degraded into a flame war from which there is no escape."

Comment: why isn't fraud detection included in recalc?

Comment: @genesis Analyzing every vote you've gotten is more complex than simply summing them up to get a score.

Comment: @MatthewRead: So separate link to "remove downvotes given by maniacs" ?