# Someone seems to be systematically upvoting my responses

Tags: discussion, reputation, abuse, serial-voting

I've just watched [my reputation on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643977/geekosaur?tab=reputation) jump over 100 over the past 5 minutes or so due to someone upvoting all my recent responses in a batch,

[image]

Is there anything in place on Stack Exchange to try to avoid that kind of abuse?  (Recognition is nice, but not essential.  Systematic upvoting makes me feel [soiled](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soiled#Adjective).)

Comment: also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93142/what-do-i-do-if-i-suspect-someone-has-downvoted-a-lot-of-my-posts

Comment: If the votes are still present after a duration of time where it is likely the script should have been run (sadly I don't know how often they run), and you want more information, flag for a moderator to help, it's easy enough to identify who did this and send of an email asking for clarification. Considering the answers you're getting upvotes for are all over the map in terms of topics, it is highly unlikely the same user (and it *is* just one user this time) is that elated about all those. Of course, it could be you've just posted the moderlode of good content for that person :)

Answer (score 3):

A process runs every once in a while and detects fraudulent votes and removes them.

> SO runs scripts and checks for this kind of behaviour every 24 hours, so it should be fixed up soon.

From [joshhunt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes/21576#21576)'s answer on this question:

> [I was just attacked by an onslaught of downvotes! What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21575/144987)

Comment: need source link to documentation here on MSO, but can't seem to find the link? if someone can help me find it and post as a comment, I'll add it in

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes