# Why is not there some downvote validation?

Tags: feature-request, support, reputation, down-votes, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial downvotes in quick succession on all my posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/serial-downvotes-in-quick-succession-on-all-my-posts)

I have been an active member of Stack Overflow for the last 2 weeks (although a registered member for just 6 months).

Today at around 1 p.m. (+5.30 GMT), I had some 149 rep. But within 2 hours I got 19 downvotes!!! In fact downvotes were on my all 19 replies that I had made so far. They included 4 accepted answers. Now, that can't be  a coincidence, I think. Some people are intentionally downvoting users with low answer counts. I have verified it. Actually on the questions, where I have been downvoted, all other replies including the question itself are downvoted.

So, why shouldn't be there some kind of downvote validation?

Also, is there any way to get my hard earned rep back? :P

Comment: There's really no guarantee that it's the same person... There are a *lot* of active users on Stack Overflow at any given time.

Comment: @Cody the answers are not so bad - no way they got downvoted in the same time "for real". Such thing happened to me too recently with all my questions and top answers. Guess we got trolls in the system.

Comment: ....... _rep-o_?

Comment: How did you verify that people downvote those with low answer counts?

Comment: I see that most downvotes were indeed cancelled. So it's all good now?

Comment: Yeah, i verified them now. :) I am happy. Thanks a lot you all.

Answer (score 6):

There is already.

Such patterns are recognized by automatic daily jobs, downvotes are cancelled and the reputation is recalculated.

Wait one day and see for yourself, it happened to me as well couple of weeks ago.

For the record, I'm really supporting automatic system that will prevent me from downvoting someone - let everyone downvote whoever they want, and if the system identifies "trolling" like in your case, it will handle it.

If the downvotes won't be cancelled within two days or it happens again, report here and I'm sure the moderators will handle this.

Comment: Or just get rid of down-votes.

Comment: @dba - what do you mean by that?

Comment: It is my opinion, and not one widely shared here, that down-voting really doesn't serve a purpose.

Comment: @dbasnett: Yes it does. It encourages better content. I just downvoted 5 questions this morning because they were poorly laid out, no real queston, and there was about 3-4 comments from users saying about the same thing, "what is your question?". You want upvotes, write good questions. Its that simple.

Comment: @Shadow It would be a nice penalty to trollers to get a little "brand" to their avatar, or some such, for 24 hrs after such an attack. Like a little watermark stamp with a picture of a troll :)

Comment: @dbasnett: Yes, that's quite an unusual opinion. Downvoting is the logical opposite of upvoting, both of which are used to rank the questions in terms of helpfulness and accuracy. You'll note that unlike other online forums, answers aren't (by default) displayed in the order in which they are posted. Instead, they're posted in order of votes. This way, the community can audit answers for content and quality, and move them up or down the page relative to other answers. I can't imagine what you think is *harmful* about downvoting. Remember we're not downvoting *users*, we're downvoting *posts*.

Comment: @dba - fair enough, but most of the community plus the developers think differently so it's not really relevant. Personally, without downvoting SO will get flooded with bad contents and it's real threat to the community.

Comment: @TLP nah, that would be just noise - what I'll do is send such trolls to the Penalty Box after repeated abuse of the system.

Comment: @Cody - why can't no up-vote serve the purpose?  It amazes me at how often I read that the down-vote is about the post and not the person behind the post.  That might be the intention, but do a search here and tell me if that is the reality?  Do an online search for 'Psychology of Online Forums'.

Comment: @shadow - do you have some factual data to back that up, or is it just an opinion shared by many?  I participate in other places without the ability to down-vote and I don't see the anarchy prescribed by those defending the down-vote.  Yesterday, for voicing this opinion again, some users down-voted some old posts(over a year old) of mine.

Comment: @dbasnett: I could answer that here, but this is fairly unrelated to the question being asked. You should start a new Meta question if you have some detailed statistics to back this up. Yes, it's an opinion; it goes because it is indeed widely held by many. I can't see why that's a reason to reject it on face.

Comment: @dba I agree with Cody, start new discussion and see for yourself. I can't go to the future so can't answer your question.

Comment: @dbasnett: Maybe it wasn't a good question back then but no one downvoted it because the community's opinion on questions were different. Granted in the beginning of SO, there were a lot of subjective questions asked that probably shouldn't have but over the past year the inherent quality of questions has been raised and we will continue to raise it through meticulous downvoting, commenting, or editing.

Comment: First of all I can no longer post questions here because I have been a bad boy(that hardly ever happens).  Second; I have learned that it is not OK to have an opinion that varies from the masses.  If I were able to post the question I might get enough down votes to just disappear ;)  In the early days of Ethernet it was a widely held opinion that the speed was 10Mbps.  At a large government agency I made a roomful of gov't managers angry when I told them the facts, that it was maybe 10Mbps, often not.

Comment: @dba it's OK to hold different opinion, but you can't expect everyone to agree with it and there's a way to express such different opinion. You were blocked because you didn't provide any useful content here, just content that has been massively downvoted. I don't really agree with such harsh measures, but can understand why they exist.

Comment: I want to believe that I provide "some" useful content.  I understand that the powers-that-be have decided to allow down voting, and I am sure that they have their reasons.  If someone posted a question here about the validity of down voting and that question was immune from any voting we might all be surprised at the input.  Down voting can't go away, we can't now point out that the King has no clothes.

Comment: @dba I see your point and personally think majority of the community will disagree - can't tell though, so let's leave it at this. Anyhow, you're posting useful contents in the "parent" SO site only `Meta` is different - downvote here means "I don't personally agree", not the post wasn't helpful in general.

Comment: If it were me and I wanted to know the benefit of down voting, I would make a few changes.  Allow posts to be down voted with a penalty to the person down voting(doubled with no comment) and no penalty to the person posing the question.

Comment: it seems that it has become a war b/w upvoters and downvoters. btw i liked the idea of dbasnett. downvote must have a penalty. and a comment is mandatory. that way you can also limit the max no. of downvotes a person can vote for.

Comment: @Nishchay probably people who saw it here.. but when one member is mass downvoting/upvoting other member's posts it should be nuked by the system after day or so.

Comment: @Nishchay: There used to be a penalty, but it was removed less than a month ago. There is a limit on upvotes/downvotes. You have an equal limit daily for both. Comment votes (which cost nothing and give nothing) also have a limit.

Comment: @BrAvada, @Nishchay, there is still a -1 hit for downvotes against answers.

Comment: @Michael: Yep, I was referring to questions only.

Comment: @dbasnett: I didn't realize you had been automatically blocked from asking questions on Meta. I'm sympathetic to your situation; we see it occasionally afflicting users that it probably shouldn't. As you know, it's effective on Stack Overflow for reducing the amount of truly egregious questions that get posted, and it's worked very well for that. The problem is that downvotes traditionally are seen as meaning something different on Meta sites, namely *disagreement* with the idea that you are proposing. Nothing wrong with that in itself, but it is unfortunate it blocks minority opinions.

Comment: There used to be -1 penalty for downvotes (and there still is on *answers*) but it was recently removed on questions because everyone agreed that it was enough deterrent to keep even high rep users from downvoting posts very often. Since downvotes are one of the primary way that we filter obviously bad questions from extremely large sites like Stack Overflow, the penalty was removed. Overall, I think this has been a positive change on SO. Again, the case may be different on Meta sites. Downvotes mean something different here, and perhaps they shouldn't have a penalty inflicted upon the asker.

Comment: *Per-site* metas have solved this problem by not tracking reputation. Stack Overflow's meta (this one) is the only meta site that maintains a reputation score of its own, separate from the parent site. This is because the Stack Overflow meta is also used as the parent meta for the Stack Exchange engine that powers *all* of the sites. All of those things conspire to make it a strange bird, and people have just come to accept that things are different here. The only thing I see as problematic is when you're excluded from providing feedback because of it. But don't change the voting system on SO.

Comment: @Cody good points, I would certainly go for removing the automatic block here on Meta. Worst case, if someone keep asking really bad stuff that is not constructive for others, probably moderator can apply the question ban manually.