# Is it possible to trace serial down-voting?

Tags: support, serial-voting, anonymous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial downvotes in quick succession on all my posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/serial-downvotes-in-quick-succession-on-all-my-posts)

Someone just went through all my questions and answers and down-voted them, without comment. I want to know who this user is. Is this possible? If not, why not?

Comment: Your title asks about *an* anonymous downvote but your question is about serial voting. Those are completely different issues.

Comment: Your question aside, [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim) describes how to deal with serial downvoting.

Comment: Could you edit my question then?

Comment: @mre: You can always edit your own question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to know who this user is. Is this possible?

No. That's a *really bad idea*. In fact, you shouldn't even try to *guess* at it - chances are, you'll be wrong and end up lashing out at someone who was just trying to help... But even if you're right, going after someone just perpetuates a hostile environment on the site. [Read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59488/possible-behavior-problem/98612#98612) and tell me it wouldn't have been better if the user being down-voted had just left things to the system and mods...

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible. The key word [used to be] found in your question title: "anonymous".

However, the good news is that we have an automatic script that runs periodically (about once a day) that *does* detect suspicious voting patterns. If it identifies such in your case, the erroneous downvotes will be cleared and your reputation will be returned to you.

This way, downvotes still remain anonymous, but true cases of abuse like serial downvoting can be detected and dealt with humanely. Of course, it's always possible that the downvotes came from different users in a short window—we do have a *lot* of active users on Stack Overflow at any given time. In that case, the automated script won't help you much and you'll just have to learn to deal with some occasional rep loss. There's no way to force people to explain why they've downvoted your posts.

Answer (score -2):

again, as I decribe to your thread really IGNORE that, and in case that you'll find out whom/who is this user, what will be your steps, down-vote your posts, post some hot words, ... not good idea found ..., take that just as fun by some from us :-)