# Is it possible to view who was responsible for serial voting?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I was just attacked by an onslaught of downvotes! What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/i-was-just-attacked-by-an-onslaught-of-downvotes-what-do-i-do)
>   [Is it possible to trace serial down-voting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98675/is-it-possible-to-trace-serial-down-voting)

Is it possible to see who has serial up/down voted you or is voting completely anonymous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible to see who has serial voted on any other user's questions/answers. Actually, this information can only be seen by the actual user (who has done such action) and core moderators.

All the voting information (serial or regular) is hidden for normal users like us.

Comment: @Lucifer... I figured as much. But figured I would ask. Thanks for your help.

Comment: CHAOS (spelled with an *S*) does not have access to voting data; they're a outreach and promotion team, and have nothing to do with this type of data.

Comment: @waiwai933 (CHAOS) being a moderators on all the sites, I am sure they can view all the details. are you sure about your part ?

Comment: @Lucifer: CHAOS don't have permanent diamonds on all the sites; each member _may_ be given temporary mod powers only for the sites he or she is assigned to.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Ok, Its a new information for me :), Thank you