# getting downvoted for no reason in several minutes

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial downvotes in quick succession on all my posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/serial-downvotes-in-quick-succession-on-all-my-posts)

That is just my opinion but I think somebody keeps downvoting me for no reason.Questions, answer everything.I do not know why.Here is an image of my reputation tab

[image: in approximately 1 or 2 minutes I guess]

I have several upvotes with those answers and questions, and some of them are my solutions to my questions.

I don't really care about the reputation so much, but I really want to know my fault so I can correct it.

Any ideas about anything wrong with those questions and answer will be appreciated and I will immediately edit them.

[My reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/647884/johnnycagewins?tab=reputation)

Comment: Somebody doesn't like you answering your own questions. But it's perfectly OK to do so.

Comment: One for the question and one for the answer as much as I understand. @Chris

Comment: Unrelated - you are the first person I see whose profile text says *moderator removed*. I can't help but wonder what was in there?

Comment: This looks like somebody and their sock puppet doing the voting though

Comment: @Johnny Yeah, I just realized that. I would tend to agree with Robert's guess.

Comment: thanks Mr.Harvey I am not really that passionate about answerng my own question.It is just I had a problem and had no solutions then I found it out myself and asnwered for others, hoping it can help them.Thanks for your support.

Comment: @Eat it was basically not professional.

Comment: @Johnny Don't get the wrong idea: *[it is entirely acceptable to answer your own questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to/2729#2729)*. Some people do prefer that you wait about a day before posting your own answer, though, just to give others a chance to provide theirs.

Comment: @Chris thanks Chris, I usually wait till I find a solution and that generally takes more than one day but I will be more careful about that subject if I have to answer my own question again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens all the time. There must be a hate voter out there. Not to worry. There's a nightly script that will recalc your rep. back again. If you still have the problem tomorrow, post here and a moderator will take care of it.

Cheers.

Comment: thank you I will do that Junkie, cheers.

Comment: No problem, but next time do a search because there are loads of questions out there about the same issue.

Comment: I know I was just hoping for some suggestions to edit if there were anything wrong with my questions.

Comment: Actually a moderator would not be able to take care of this, at least i think that's what i've been told when this happened to me the last time...

Comment: @H.B. Mods can check to see if there's been suspicious voting against you, but they can't revoke the votes

Comment: @Michael, It appears that these downvotes may be sufficiently infrequent (3-4 per day @ apparently different times) to *not* trigger the recalc.  Perhaps a dev could look at it -- should it continue -- as it's only amounted to ~ -20 rep?